# Repeat Repetitive Repetitions

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

Your challenge is to generate this string:

```
011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000
```

or split into lines with length of 80:

```
01101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101
10101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000
11010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011
01011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001
10101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110
10110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110
10110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010
11010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101
01101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101
10101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010
11010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011
01011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011
01011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101
01101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110
10110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010
11010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000011010110
10110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010
11010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010
11010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011
01001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101
10100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110
10011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011
01001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101
00110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101
00110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100
11010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010
01101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001
10101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100
11010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011
01011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011
01011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101
01101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110
10110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010
11010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000001101011010110100110
10110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010
11010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010
11010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011
01011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101
10101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110
10110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011
01011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101
01101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101
01101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101
10100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010
11010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011
01001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101
10101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110
10011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110
10110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010
01101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101
01101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100
11010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010
11010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001
10101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011
01011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110
10110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110
10110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101
01101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101
01101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010
11010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101
10101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011
01011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011
01011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110
10110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110
10110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101
01101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010
11010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101
10101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101
10100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011
01011010110101101001101011010110100000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101
10100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011
01011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110
10011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101
01101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101
00110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010
11010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010
01101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101
10101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001
10101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110
10110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011
01011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101
01101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110
10110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010
11010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010
11010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011
01011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101
10101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110
10110100110101101011010000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101
10101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110
10110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110
10110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010
11010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101
01101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101
10100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010
11010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011
01001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011
01001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101
00110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110
10011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010
01101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101
00110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100
11010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100
11010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011
01011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001
10101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110
10110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011
01011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101
01101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101
01101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101
10101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010
11010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011
01011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101
10101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110
10110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110
10110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010
11010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101
01101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101
10100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010
11010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011
01000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011
01011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101
00001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110
10110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010
00001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110
10110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010
00110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010
11010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000
01101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101
10101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000
11010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011
01011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011
01011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101
01101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110
10110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010
11010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101
01101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101
10101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101
10101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110
10110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011
01011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101
01101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000001101011
01011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101
01101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101
01101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101
10100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010
11010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011
01001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101
10100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110
10011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110
10011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010
01101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101
00110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100
11010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010
01101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001
10101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001
10101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110
10110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011
01011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101
01101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110
10110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010
11010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010
11010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011
01011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101
10101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110
10110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011
01011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101
01101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101
01101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101
10100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010
11010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011
01001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101
10101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110
10011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110
10110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010
01101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101
01101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100
11010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100000110101101011010011010110101101
01101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100
11010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101
10101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011
01011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011
01011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110
10110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110
10110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101
01101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010
11010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101
10101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101
10101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011
01011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011
01011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110
10110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101
01101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010
11010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010
11010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101
10101101011010110100110101101011010000
```

### Notes:

- You may return an array of the characters (or digits) of the string
- You may use characters other than 0 and 1 if you want.
- You can have other characters in the output, as long as, if filtered for your two chosen characters, would result in this pattern.
- This string is generatable in way better ways than just hardcoding the whole string. A big part of the challenge is to find the shortest way to generate it. I've made a 16-byte SOGL answer that *should* be a language-agnostic algorithm (an old SOGL version specific 15-byte answer is what inspired the challenge), trough I'm not gonna post it (until someone finds that algorithm) to make the challenge more interesting for others.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer (per language) wins!

#### Snippet to check the validness of an answer:

```js
function check() {
  if (chr0.value == "") chr0.value = "0"
  if (chr1.value == "") chr1.value = "1"
  inp.value = inp.value.replace(new RegExp("[^"+JSON.stringify(chr0.value+chr1.value)+"]", "g"), "")
  if (inp.value == correct)
    output.innerHTML = "Matches"
  else
    output.innerHTML = "Doesn't match"
}
correct = "011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000"
```

```html
<input id="inp" placeholder="input your result here"/><br>
<input id="chr0" placeholder="character for 0 (def=0)"/>
<input id="chr1" placeholder="character for 1 (def=1)"/><br>
<button id="chk" onclick="check()">check</button>
<div id=output></div>
```

Comment: Do you know if there are any better ways than base compression?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Definitely, as this was made as a 15 byte accident :p `A big part of the challenge is to find the shortest way to generate it.`

Comment: Yeah, that's the reason I deleted my answer...felt not really worth it. Oh, and what you quoted is why I asked.

Comment: 1 question: why?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I was playing around with an old SOGL version, then accidentally got that :p

Comment: This appears to be a primitive sequence, so it isn't a trivial repetition of anything unfortunately :(

Comment: Puzzling.SE meets codegolf.SE. Of course, when someone recreates the original method, it's just plain old golfing.

Comment: @Sanchises Well, then there's still the possibility to recreate something even golfier. ;)

Comment: Am I the only one that can't see the bits behind the scrollbar on the 90-chars-per-line split view?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts How many characters do you see fully?

Comment: @dzaima 89 characters on each line. The last one is mostly behind the scrollbar, rendered on Chrome in Windows 7

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yeah, Chrome does render the scrollbar over the characters. 87 should hopefully be fine for most browsers

Comment: I can only see 82 w/o scrolling.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline dammit browsers -_-

Comment: Probably the fact that I'm using my laptop (not that I use anything else for PPCG)

Comment: Wait doesn't Chrome add a horizontal scrollbar if the vertical scrollbar is rendered over characters?

Answer (score 35):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>35</s> <s>33</s> <s>29</s> <s>26</s> <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
'1
#˜5s £=r1,26¤²²sX
s#ž
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9qYXB0//8nMQojwpg1cyDCoz1yMSwyNsKkwrLCsnNYCnMjwp7//w)

#### Explanation

```
'1   First line: Set variable U to this value.
'1   Yield the string "1". (This part gets simpler every time I golf this answer...)

1525s £=r1,26¤²²sX   Second line: Set variable V to this value (though that's not important).
1525s                Yield the string "1525".
      £              For each char X in this string:
           26¤         Yield the binary representation of 26. "11010"
              ²²       Double it twice.                       "11010110101101011010"
                sX     Slice off the first X chars. This gives "1010110101101011010",
                       "110101101011010", "010110101101011010", and "110101101011010".
       =               Set U to
        r1,              U with each instance of 1 replaced with the string calculated above.

s158   Last line: output the result of this line.
s158   Take U and slice off the first 158 characters.
```

Here's how I got this. Start with the original sequence:

```
01101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011...
```

After some messing around, I realized that the sequence consisted entirely of copies of `0` and `11010`. Replacing each instance of `11010` with `2` gave this:

```
02220222222022202222220222022222202220002220222222022202222220222022222202220002220222...
```

Oh hey, now it's entirely made of `0` and `222`. Let's change each `222` to a single `2`:

```
02022020220202202000202202022020220200020220202202022020020220202202022020002022020220...
```

This sequence looks an awful lot like the original. There seems to be a lot of `22020`s in this, so I replaced each with `3` and got this:

```
02033300203330020333020333002033300203330203330020333000203330203330020333002033302033...
```

Now each instance of `3` is contained in a `020333`. Replacing each of these again with a single `3` gives this:

```
30303303033030033030330303303003303033030330303303033030330300330303303033030033030330...
```

...and we're back to the original pattern again. One more time, replacing `33030` with `4`:

```
30304404440444444044404444440444044444404440
```

Uh-oh, there's some stray chars at the beginning. We can fix this by adding an extra `3` at the beginning before condensing (this is where the 158 extra chars at the end comes from). Then we condense each run of 3 `4`s into a single `4`, as before:

```
4040440404404044040
```

Aaaaand yet again, we're back to the original pattern. One last time, let's condense copies of `44040` to `5`:

```
4040555
```

Hopefully this final step isn't too hard to understand. It's like the step where we compressed the `020333`s into `3`s, except this time, we're compressing `4040555`s into `5`s:

```
5
```

And there you have the fully compressed string. The code simply reverses the repeated compression to get back the original string. Since all compression iterations were nearly identical, it doesn't take much to reorganize the string properly.

Comment: As you can see [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135650/41024) I've used Jelly's `/` (reduce)...does Japt have reduce/fold too? If so, that might save bytes.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Japt does have reduce, but that would require changing `£=` to at least `r@` if not something longer. (Honestly, `£=` is not a high price to pay for an unconventional reduce function)

Comment: You meant `r@<space>`? Of course then it would be something like `[[1], 1, 5, 2, 5]` instead of `[1, 5, 2, 5]` with using reduce.

Comment: Uh... no? (I'm on mobile ATM so apologies if I made a typo)

Comment: You didn't type `r@ ` but markdown is a bit confusing that's why I asked...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer True. A space there would transpile to `()` though, which is a SyntaxError in JS

Comment: Would it be accurate to say you just reverse-engineered a fractal expansion?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yep, pretty much.

Comment: [23 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=I3MyNXMgrHLIclrOMjaksrJzWcNzI54)

Answer (score 14):

### JavaScript (ES6), 130 bytes

Multicolor nonlinear pulse compression by consecutive optical parametric amplification in quasi-phase matched structures.

<sup>OK, not quite. Just substitutions.</sup>

```js
f=(n=0,s='pqh0f9bc9bc9bc900')=>n<20?f(n+1,s.split((n+9).toString(36)).join('cb0dgfgnjkkoppo0qs10'[n]+'adcdef0hi0klmnqpqrs1'[n])):s
```

#### Demo

```js
f=(n=0,s='pqh0f9bc9bc9bc900')=>n<20?f(n+1,s.split((n+9).toString(36)).join('cb0dgfgnjkkoppo0qs10'[n]+'adcdef0hi0klmnqpqrs1'[n])):s

o.innerHTML = f()
```

```html
<pre id=o></pre>
```

#### How?

This is definitely not the best way to compress this string, but I thought I'd post it anyway since I went to the trouble of optimizing it (slightly) with a recursive function.

We start with the string `s="pqh0f9bc9bc9bc900"` and successively apply the following 20 substitutions:

```
 9  | a  | b  | c  | d  | e  | f  | g  | h  | i  | j  | k  | l  | m  | n  | o  | p  | q  | r  | s
----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----
 ca | bd | 0c | dd | ge | ff | g0 | nh | ji | k0 | kk | ol | pm | pn | oq | 0p | qq | sr | 1s | 01
```

For instance, a *"9"* will expand to *"ca"*, *"cbd"*, *"c0cd"*, *"dd0ddd"*, ..., and ultimately a 2381-character string of 0's and 1's.

Comment: Interesting technique, I'm sure it'd work well on strings with less pattern than this.

Comment: You lost me at "multicolor"

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 128 bytes

```
Fold[StringReplace,"AAAY0PY0",{{"A"->"Y0PY0PYP"},{"Y"->"P0P0PP0P0PP0P0"},{"P"->"QQQXXX00"},{"Q"->"XXX0XXXXXX0"},{"X"->"01101"}}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvvfLT8nJTq4pCgzLz0otSAnMTlVR8nR0THSICDSQEmnulrJUUnXTgnMDYgMUKrVqVaKBIkEGAAhnACLB4DEAwMDIyIiDCAigSAREDcCDCCCESBBA0NDA0Ol2trY/wFAq0sUHNL@AwA)

Comment: Couldn't you make this shorter by using just one StringReplace and having a list of replacement rules?

Comment: yes of course...I just started golfing this down...

Comment: If the replacement is that easy then Retina should do well...

Answer (score 6):

## Retina, <s>69</s> <s>66</s> 65 bytes

Port of @ETHproduction's JavaScript (ES6) answer: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fy/DQNkMDQwMrKzDBVZ1gqGFvq6d1aJtGTIqWppUml4phVFQUVxSXIUgZV61hAlDciosrTq/a0NSitubQNq7//wE) N.B. Somewhat slow.

```
1¶1010::010::
{`1(?=.*¶(\d*):)
$1ZZZ
Z
11010
}1`\d*:

^.{158}|¶
```

A port of @Jenny_mathy's Mathematica answer was <s>82</s> 66 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcWhEYBQDERB/6q5X0I6SKISHAKBQTD0Hxhmxd7Hc177DGbW8hbGv7fTbP5hw@XCiYiUCFKZIqkqCq2lNfMC)

```
AAAY0PY0
A
Y0PY0PYP
Y
ZPZPZ
Z
P0P0
P
QQQR00
Q
R0RR0
R
XXX
X
01101
```

A port of @ETHproduction's Japt explanation was 69 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYYxCoBADAT7fYxssnvgawQLCxsLuU58ewwyDDP3Mc9rr8LwDwZME4bdQqIIgUlJPZm9yG6LCAaxLU@M9UXVBw)

```
5454545
5
4040
4
444
4
33030
3
020333
3
22020
2
222
2
11010
^.{158}
```

A port of @ETHproduction's previous Japt explanation was also 69 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fKz4@3tDAkCueC0gCaSA0hJBALpAGSxtApMECyNJxetWGpua1XP//AwA)

```
___101
_
10101
1
111
1
11010
1
___100
_
10110
1
111
1
11010
^.{157}
```

A port of @RickHitchcock's JavaScript answer was 74 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcU7DoBADAPRfk7jHAkpv20oEPcPLAV@kueKe53HDCu3LrHoLppSUqRe/5GENneXCHb9G47MZDMP)

```
ifififhg0
i
hhg
h
g0f
g
f0f0ff0f0ff0f0
f
e0e0e0ddd00
e
ddd0dddddd
d
01101
```

A port of @Arnauld's JavaScript answer was 85 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcpBCsAgDADB@74mPfqcqiWWgCS1/089FBbmss/13vPMxGOISqntT4RCq52KNBq901HdD8ocDMxMMMTdJ3MbOBEE61gs5Mj8AA)

```
pqh0g09bc9bc9bc900
9
cbd
b
0c
c
dd
d
gg0g0
g
nh
h
kkk0
k
0pppn
n
0pq
p
qq
q
s1s
s
01
```

Comment: Nice! can you please update mine? (this is my final version) thanx!

Comment: @Jenny_mathy I was able to golf off some more bytes so you're now the leading Retina port, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>85</s> 80 bytes

```
[j="1",5,2,5].map(x=>j=j.replace(/1/g,"11010".repeat(4).slice(x)))&&j.slice(158)
```

Somewhat of a port of my Japt answer. An explanation of the pattern can be found over there.

#### Test snippet

```js
var q = [j="1",5,2,5].map(x=>j=j.replace(/1/g,"11010".repeat(4).slice(x)))&&j.slice(158);

var o = "011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000110101101011010011010110101101011010110101101001101011010110100110101101011010110101101011010011010110101101001101011010110101101011010110100110101101011010000";

console.log(q === o);
```

Comment: It's a bit confusing...until you find out `j="1"` is actually two things, one of them being type-abused.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>28</s> <s>22</s> 20 bytes

```
⁽.⁷Dð26Bẋ4ṫȧ€Ẏð/ṫ159
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R4169R43bXQ5vMDJzerir2@ThztUnlj9qWvNwV9/hDfpAnqGp5f//AA)

-3 thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan).

(Somewhat) port of [ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions)'s excellent Japt [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135517/41024).

Still not efficient as [dzaima's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135486/repeat-repetitive-repetitions/135650#comment331265_135486) (old SOGL version)!

This returns an array of digits.

Comment: This has been checked for validity using [Diff Checker](https://www.diffchecker.com/)!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62784/discussion-between-erik-the-outgolfer-and-jonathan-allan).

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>158</s> <s>143</s> 139 bytes

*(Saved some bytes thanks to @DanTheMan.)*

```
'ifififhg0'[r='replace'](/i/g,'hhg')[r](/h/g,'g0f')[r](/g/g,'f0f0ff0f0ff0f0')[r](/f/g,'e0e0e0ddd00')[r](/e/g,'ddd0dddddd')[r](/d/g,'01101')
```

```js
console.log('ifififhg0'[r='replace'](/i/g,'hhg')[r](/h/g,'g0f')[r](/g/g,'f0f0ff0f0ff0f0')[r](/f/g,'e0e0e0ddd00')[r](/e/g,'ddd0dddddd')[r](/d/g,'01101'));
```

Comment: You just need to generate the string, so you could drop the `_=>`.

Comment: This could be quite a bit shorter (at least 30 bytes). Hint #1: switch from `.replace(/x/g,y)` to `.split(x).join(y)`

Comment: Hint #2: Use digits > `1` in place of the letters in the compression. This will allow you to easily replace e.g. `9`, then `8`, then `7`, etc.

Comment: @ETHproductions, I see how I can save 1 byte by switching to `split` and `join` with template strings:  `'ifififhg0'[s='split']BTiBT[j='join']BThhgBT[s]BThBT[j]BTg0fBT` (where BT is backtick)

Comment: Hint #3: map through an array of replacements, e.g. `j='string',i=9,[replacements].map(x=>j=j.split(i--).join(x)),j`

Comment: Thanks, @ETHproductions, I understand now.  Working on a program to find the shortest possible pattern in the string, but doubtful it will be shorter than yours.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 20 bytes

```
1Ž5ûv1₂b4×y.$.:]Ƶv.$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8Ohe08O7ywwfNTUlmRyeXqmnomcVe2xrmZ7K////dXXz8nVzEqsqAQ)

Port of [ETHProductions's JAPT answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135517/6484).

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://github.com/ngn/k), 86 bytes

```
@[&15558;+\(,/(,/(,/(1 5,,/(1_,/(11#5 6 6),\:5 5),\:4 5),\:9#3 2 3),\:2 2),\:1 2);:;1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/98hWs3Q1NTUwlo7RkNHH4oMFUx1QFQ8iDBUNlUwUzDT1ImxMlUwBVEmEMpS2VjBSMEYxDRSMAJRhkDK2sraMPb/fwA)