# Compress my Malbolge!

Tags: code-challenge, compression

### Background

Malbolge is truly intriguing language. But programs written in it are also extraordinairly huge (and in some cases, unpostable on PPCG).

Your challenge (shall you accept it) is, to compress and decompress given normalized Malbolge program. Devise your own lossless algorithm. You may compress your data further using an existing algorithm afterwards, but you must cite the algorithm used. You may use dictionaries.

### Input

On the input, there will be given (in most cases very long) string, containing only following characters: `i</*jpov`. Example data:

```
iooooooooooooooooooooovoooioooipooooo<ooooooooooivojo<<<<<oio*ioooooooooooooooopiooooooooooooooooooo/jpooooooooooo
```

[Example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KrzysztofSzewczyk/codegolf-submissions/master/h0.mn) bigger chunk of data, 86 kilobytes big.

### Output

Well, not very much to say about it, output depends on the algorithm.

### Rules:

- Input taken by your program, compressed, and then decompressed, shall be identical.
- Submissions are scored by the following formula: \$ \frac{Compressed}{Original} \times 100\% \$, applied to the example 86 kilobytes big chunk.
- If a submission abuses the fact that only one example chunk is provided (eg. by hardcoding it), I reserve right to add more example chunks.
- Standard loopholes are forbidden, I/O rules apply.

Note: 7zip with PPMd algorithm manages to compress the code with 2,95% score.

Comment: Is our submission supposed to include both a compressor and decompressor code?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork yes. You may submit this as two programs, functions, whatever.

Comment: This could be a great challenge, but it's currently very flawed. The scoring method strongly encourages hardcoding, and "I reserve the right to retroactively make existing solutions invalid" isn't a good solution *at all*. Compression challenges typically solve this by counting the size of (compressed data + decompressor).

Comment: @Grimy Well, you may be right. But I'd like to check what are the most efficient compressors community can make. I made myself one that has 1,1% score. If there was golfing need, the submissions would balance code size and the ratio, and I don't want THAT.

Comment: You *think* you don't want that, but without that, the score can be driven arbitrarily low by using larger and larger dictionaries, which is honestly quite boring. Or straight up 0% by hardcoding (you say you may add more test cases, but nothing prevents one from hardcoding those too).

Comment: @Grimy you're not right. People who put effort into their answers will downvote boring solutions (because well, they may better, but technically not, AND because they put a lot of time into their solution, and somebody has JUST came up to the party with simple and boring solution), punishing fun destroyers and effectively making them remove crappy answers.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/135486/58974)

Comment: CGCC is not a popularity contest. Most answerers are not trying to gather upvotes, but to optimize for the question’s objective winning criterion. If that criterion makes it so that only boring solutions can win, that’s an issue with the question.

Comment: @Grimy why the popularity-contest tag tho? Who cares about being boring, I'm reaching half a hundred answers, every single one made in either Brainfuck or Malbolge

Comment: Challenges on CGCC should be self-contained. You should add a description of what exactly each command does, and how normalised Malbolge interprets a program

Comment: @JoKing umm, what? Why should I. Does the information alter the way the code can be compressed?

Comment: oh nvm, i was thinking this was a [tag:meta-golf] challenge, where the output had to still be runnable. Isn't this just a straight compression challenge that has nothing to do with Malbolge then?

Comment: @JoKing sure! You're right, partially.

Answer (score 2):

## Score with test 1: 38.6%, Score with test 2: 4.9%

## Compressor

### [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 97 bytes

```
ṡ2ṢŒɠżQƊ1ị>ɗƇ3NÞḣ8Ṫ€,‘ɼ$€Ẏœṣ;@W}ɗjƭƒ
7©ṛ⁸“i</*jpov”iⱮ’Ç31¡
“i</*jpov”iⱮḅ8b256,ÇĖF€LÞḢL;L};÷/$ʋ,ḷɗ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7V1LiyTHEb7rZyw6NQuLJGwLdjE6@bQYdNLd4MMkgszTgg@CtcAsWOCDDFoLP7Ckk41t8Ek7sk4a78L4X/T8kXFPd3W98hXPrJ6uGCGpujIzKrPyyy8jIjOy3C8//vhXt7fby6/e3V5@/frz67@@/v7DN799Z/ufz356/fLNi/d@fvWX7atv3t9e/v3m0388vHn@h@vv395dbb/73evfby@/efzBR59cv3Rv/vnm87d@8sPftpd/vPn1q5vnf7p48mjjgn928/zPFzf//tfN8y@vXrz3zg9fvRWnbV/95v1fvPujHz@8evHfL362k/307pFfP3389JPHV98@evt/nz3cvvr2@uXt1Ytd4u3tgwuf@nu2@/cu5SLsfz4ZUi6eeeef3P3tMmyi0iEl75ELo18PHmYeKvrM7J9zh/8E77riftNd7h7cXd5V4Xh3/2t@d38Z3FCH/m53ub8eMmzGP0Ylupxhkrrxfvzseeqx5uF4Nxze79390P3/INQdCvc1GvKN7m98VLfajU0yC@DW3SsbVyNZXbcJmYJ@DCQ3QdWucFe8F@@nGXa/u8cD83X162ET0k87Vr6X5kPmqaGU3mUYQBpmTwvjV@anGeZt27/CTJYuz2g0hFKzRg@cvoGoWcn0YbgcnzZqZf80P004lj42I5HkhzHbCx5alW3GqJemYlNS4/uHFDf@ETdjXJFE6dT9/fX4B6INo9ebkJq8fxhek59lRI8zprs@kT65vx/P8xvDE0P8pP3vGQyipNn9A2vEt5JonrQ@LS1zvyOn1E3QS9xnzklO3z/yYfp2BMBRcuYVjhLjlJ59cwl5LI4zHnESqnl8YebIJ2Wb3WWZ4nRW5@QrmRRMpO6SXfY@tO@HJhQGUiJfKr0bRtmUCvIn7zM5hZQz73O4Xpdy8Q0Qiw0FonpMa57K6PsxP6uxKyXNxU/rk@m4ygPHWdxUg3GpW3nAuFiXygieJs3SHPhmUcwscZ7qcrfjd@vSWuKcKIrZ5mrErBaJhNT7TWSsPiLKMM/h8gmx1pnMmMA/tECvQYRMnaKEEv4yz5ozViXjXFeK6@RDpq8mYEg@I8FXlbyRReJSt6qUlUJnhrTyWXNWU/xzmMHjmdv7XIt9PD58rKuBivTzLLZoorWcotXCKR0pgNuY7WyUKJ9VPBiiEGWTemJA9XPpHYBElQcEURSibEZXVikSz19jBZMuzfvYM5GtMShjz9qwAtWGoWQMVgOkOYIZE@Nx1gyMjO5eANYOkDHFEoCCCbUJW3AwoWBtEcuYp4eoaxCyZuM3VGtZzQhRBACCfM0UxQua3HMB0M5cphLnVwqXWR5c@C6HK3RWKTVf@3wp2JMnuXzwxRoW0wt1LJSDPn@az5ffZDE9sgKK@WN3PjT/cVhXagp8p4k6w98WIiekxrU6x/3vgXUYBha8TH8n1OvtA/Vde0SfI/PCal6pe/qdw2oyf@vo@oMw41lY93g8EPLDW0IbA548EqjtAWKLOzZIqCGVQPSQVN6@Lgd9DV0ss4YCqxZx2HMGP7lrcC@8Sgeh2DbamyeWQvWYxFAC997R1qWUTi4MoXrQo1RCXPnisGN0ZfoP18FoGSXtmCe7amWKPgMsCw0kvBR2e2URRJLmELhzAvhyQbKOhTKo/nci/exoPUAshWEMJ8INTpQFHGm8O@TIdkJj2FHHF6Mcsoel@pjcL@Ry6B6V61NG7zBKontWrm8ZvcQoSehhyT5m9RWrLKGnJfua1WessqQeR3pooO@A14PM0iQE4D3ISCm8moNKExGghQF2P7LLk7GANekR74TfyyISGGjRLR27OpJrqBIPqEthwAcKIRhkoA4BUWkAKUwYVKgH3hoYoITlQeQwEYSiIZ68oveNKAomhw0inlMSKzFiKPALk0MVH1cgZHEl4TEliCoJXGnLiLw4iBcliSYJPCnLEFIM5FEmgxF9KbIto0gTAYgkcTUEnDDkpOACnDoRmhOB9NTkY@QJgVPKkaCOH3F5YojkbxviPCEe9vKScRLFkElyakg9gaILqkFVEqy8bS102Rptp8sUBKnIdhr6M7gEoINXWcS2k5bQokjakyZ0ZcGrpwEogktJqjDMWmgG2vqBKo6lkdxQXsIqYJlbwCbMEzau6fX@yKl@v9XkYrM/AGvX6l3L@f87HAjVPXCyxWv@rL7U6OLwz1Eap9DQ@otER7rpqR@te6PcM4f2JpqeaHXinQ@tB/XuRFbuqaMHgXt33CnJFvjC46JMmf6cD7fuFRzOOek7e/RreP3TTKcJgqgPAGkEDOhCYT5is88uIiPOBxAwQc0IHRNwpLFxP6CRZsPRe8h3IgQz5fIkGKRqrEcJZ8oI9N4nwSBVBkATPITQaAKNlzNmhQr/liiWhwsP1l7ESCRxASheLjkHjJGJHJkQ9RBZNsmjKYNgmpQxjlaBofrwRKIQT0UcyNG024JmClVsQXy21mmsuZZDsqDZ2KmyEMoiXpeRTOGdok8JhZgFAJT2ssDnM4K@bFTThmpOfKJC@F1WQD04LahAIdJTlJbXDq4rmzG@JLUsgJg63VToBVRyJbZ5zV@aJ5Q8ijAIWn6myjJRZYGQpS8bD4nyUEsWAno/4cvLGDytz0MI122QnsGl5y8mjgoLlqBJzGhH24mjZIXncYMiq@qkdf4KD9KCamWIi@g1FYMR4WGvAcU4ZQGTSkGdQa5k@Wrr0bhal3KTu133dQixjp5iw8JQ2X@YZyPjoaa6jbATh6bcoKer86YYJsmoev8ktRqGegP2@cQAMoJp7rORN6Jo4EkuZCInpRXsxkHwTQlHSp4/HnQou70QiAZjylhIdoPgEhMZYNzAAI@btc5S46GxDo1uFnL@AfgVF9hiW3Ca6jqLOAEJC05SQTFrUnpgAREI9QcKqxPBF3b1k7i31PioOR@1QgxjkQIXYXP@@5KJZJRFhYpepLp6Tl2toETaGDHJElNrQLHXKSixNKYbocOm0Ob8QvMbbSqjKtpGPPJ@oEa0A10QFtSgVxkYsSANLQYquaV3i6o46dhQLbuMr09T4nL8mvf@AAmqsjVGZeuq2J5VYLRoqo6I6c6IaLnwLqWlDtBWQ07QullkAN7R5BwlBHGOd8KBy1in6Tb5FgoP5hgwDPOskGyIdlhmn4TeTnoFi54WkGz@n5PdjShORaUFVPA0BYaPsQ@cfcRoaDES4kDKqOhebEnUC2enHcqSPZ0FDaTVmGJF/Uc0Xkf95APC2Qd1gBi5tDGuTuEAsJJek8PIisLUG/FIM7wQ0SHm7jM@UeWTVsqJNGzW6xBGLkWVTCYpCGmcLEgMt5k0r3R4gfFKu2MwtHexk@Jr0iMCHHGzipO9yP4YVTeMxtI3/mAvsnJj2s0yMeqq362Shc3aTsBA6DR0imkIGpkAGnpEn9FK0yjik9vmV98mC9wpusID2sEUJKT1NPTkCG8chXCTkdJSoVdKK@AChw2udAVcjHh0@EWFYfDhemizyhhmgahzuQ8VkYOB6fb3KkgGsDZVPbBcb2JS/DQsPHzQwhbuQyynpoGFXWjA4mYN53pR/MRJhVANO/KLmhTUwNBjLKPyaeF7tVZFC3BZy@IUbf2bqM8sFeeLpRemNmyso@GlaRCMyTrcRMDitr03sO@Yc3037cPCkcuf4BV2OvaMpJqSlGYglaA9v/IldY29gopq0zJHDCLU7AyYjHs0nMynE1Eu8nmA1cU/cPcNSthoi01lAtwDDqEx@pFXfZYkH4kP3BjfyB1ewfNF3wMNKIMrhPllFLSMi0jtxK4pC4HoZpbZArSIBCSj@TTa@1XSe1iloPAxumlscGmenFPHj0hczZmutrNPCBTmGOnJKbNtCea8QQDI2KWxK1n5qzQAsFDpxU4epa54tVn1anWoUgVg0FKAzRvGSE09PE1OCoTBqBKaXAaTfT1C2@DS3xwPcVBVNgLhpjmjHelNzScxeeFxA0LOSncYUk5f52FnkaBjqupTs@4zHGTUo0Y9rb07DM257I4eQ8fIBxJVQWchwJ5mzcj0zKn@IKOeZN0b/yzFPy2/nw4z2wHlEpBa5eewmN@GUASV6mnJMPigt6KeAfOUjVEfGhzOpH2ql@o8dK5zUZrlwVMPHDrYj3YqrkNQ8VIVcNaKMPArlbLAEGMQwB5iwsLBGm1omZkE2euaq0YQBED3oWfxcNZzR3UKYaNC84w@1NCncsB5RzfV1QcWSQiio/I9KhASOKG4NgFUyUNlQqAOZxYCzGBgGQxAgKBdmKzpoH4mOZwezEYI1OV9rSmBjQwpf4PNGcQQUQlAVLbJgcMxVr7Zta4YSpiQbKCImRdolzR6Y9AqLAhhFwOhExdYpKAF49gsgTmYjaJWCJIDfcGCRBArmkaEJhI4YGRwUvn6m3CQxBnPHUCTVGLVcyGYsNwWqFAHm1KQsdnq/S/t0UZvBVxTOEwz/9ZJQEvIHYaNgjEPGEVHAds1cjBB6yf4xRFzfRH6H0IUkhiQUz@A5GDr5XKsIAmGRroI0tCxhXXl2UTCIcbafgElD5s7gF8FxLFGm@h9Ib3CzBIZZwcUI5IaRtkyKUxIPL3T7BBNeGidxskvWoeLTSiEr/ZoUgX8m6dAxacODDNGtFEhttgKBQGi983KkNyus8DMUT32p679VkpO8WJThuQaq@RZ8LBoDnz8x8riPVrFCmI38rTxcWJ38aC4w2wRxXV5YUahfdwH6GhDQMbmG9TmP4WZha9v1M9pQmqoZqhAogwbgkVUESGoomaycGlDbwIRmTSgVGHTBXCxw2N1W9lTITHLYvBJwgwTiZjEpnipGSbZA3bhakZRgFkoG2laefB/)

## Decompressor

### [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 44 bytes

```
ḅ256ḃ8
ḣ3s2ṚṣḢ}©¥jƭƒṫ5µṛ®n8Ɗ¿‘
ḢĿị“i</*jpov”
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVzLqm7HcZ7nKTQOgvT9An4RYzzMwEIkhkAgg4BIMIZkllGw44mFByaxZwEJDwwnQe@x9SLHf3116erutY9AZ@@1enVX1/Wr6svWF3/75Zf/9PHj2ze/SLW9ffOv46/evvk6/0N6@/ZXb99@/fbNb//5w@8//O6L7/7w3X@8ffvf9cP/vn376w9//Lvx3b99@PP3X/3nq/dv///Pb3/69@@/@q@f/ehv/vqLn//9P37/1W8@/t8vv/@X//nxx48/iZ9/Ftvnn4Wn/17fUq2ff9by66G8fsSpTbFXeXI/wqB@nSiW14/yopsyTTAfOu8/IpH/dJdUqUuKT19/@vlPEhEJxEUxmkXbKj01SNCFUuyTRU/1NTRFasp4fc3w@h0xEWmB/uVJor1@FLzRiDL4LYWkYiciAg5J9jiMnULsDGKx0xRgbIBP0@zrRyfeyqsX9U6YMcqMPMfrqdG3TIomlhpNU6knNcVIdBPRzV3YjJm0ltEPctKMGey82jCyYEISIKHz6x30X92ZwhA7QkZoIgeVFpMTr5itkeyJWBlVtJuIbiAvyPjYhGuoieR/vXRYtoisBSRfTZX64gWay8wvBgaam78FsN9omigGglfEodYi/uPrOxHupB1ijBjnfiS8cksapGmHuMSrvUNtSSjTlOQasQ4xGPwDvgXbhsnkhgQEhAWnoQtDjSiGJlHEegmwOdTaxWti7TxcpE0sP7lCHF1jEKqNaokQ2Ggw3JxqJdJFnPSjw4ZFIgEDE0L0NQ88akq8Eqfw4llECCaSWYfolsRPYxNs6MGos1kKmIV7BPHNOIbIRvNBEkQr@R6csrIPwoVe/2EgBQuZD@4/shBmAvQUsg6K2t6GhGBRA3eNX@izQx00pkdVDMbAf8mWMGpTtEP8cH/6AfuB5y4qiYiPnvQJSiPajmoQqVsXr4gtSAfulcUhuEeCtYwYhXFtwhT9m4q1FHtJ/BDoBmWgiV55AnhJkSZMzLZPVdwH7gAzk3cTLTALW1Fv2BkMUNCAKExH7egA6lE78DwAuxpFgcBjVga1Ib3gWxAfaQoBmf09AmebuHSRMC5TEgysyLAByE/aVFgj/JL5ATyCH7BXojxB4UBXUSOJDb0pfkDMIcbg6IY1ALncq4pTQByAKv3r4iWF0RYoKWDDdkY4A7iz@CpMh7BKgjjQF2mvmlMwRsXE8QLnFTDlPgzijLRAgKSkyFWggi72h8fGJPO1IhwQmNILfDkObkUg0Egyfh1qbXRRbUaCwBg0IYE88Aw5lp4ATDRjUoigwaQvsBoYSOBMRIuAvwtJUjOGE5rCoQCApHiaiGAsEpYCz6rMR6acWQK/StwEiZnehEgXhyMMBUY1norgC9O@2ggMyWzEj3yaksDQTLaY/E5dCY0Cz00wBSqv30MsSJBJVKhL4N/UjagS4FE3YkRievCc9KFxyFNjFfUnHkNGosAijESARaZJ7eRgxJF0G4G5oGZimgRAVhucTsnwXZNEY0XRr8huoDEK6IviHpnJJbE7vQ4eEgXwybJDc4zk@MFeQKOa5oXA3lskoTUFcXHRyGSAUcwq2ZJchvCicQ2Hx8B@Qs8UAIO9jgSlpixRJaSJHa7d2FGILcR/EV1FtgUJmSUoUaSJqlGGkVhBMmhQrHr9zjwlIiYw0wA1AbgkdmEgY6UW@V15@JCR4kv0j2ZGGpLkxoCQBc2bsDTFAF2mIds1/g3P4FRL3ZC9WSGc3V49BH2FF9LBwBvwtLNDaRlA/Yf8Jq@Q3wCQxjQamwDdRW6tOeHhKBvBQeXBk5@4pJjMJ/9HZAVZO0iIfrl0A7ZzNc/YApjFL4kgAX9hLLBUPD0jbBAsFnfjBhkSpUqm@BHPRKP/j0cwR4Lv1Z5QMxWWG2VkkvwusM7DosYpe69rQQraO1FNUcfjJ9fUWStds1Bf5FGHs6v1rDV80eJDXpgNILfMybU4f4p1Z7qzKouQg4RTyyoaqJ1as2VCWq158QXFHE/D5JRVG3Jo1WSaxOMIg6rSv1loEiS5HWNQetYFnEn8PVilNrRYBU@TIw4SmDzPfbiCSPoluBfAYWpnH4osUEc99fiJJchKh5@Ff65jZ7VggzQbx14NRwdrzBLrYFLek8QPr0fcFLxeTII/G@@PnwWbJZECJ0QQXiro4nIsvqaNOr5IK82B5W09eAevbW4dU7l4eaeZBhYpYppMYTyitk/tcdDWntiCmo@zuJmxlqJuCDjneq9tuD0LjpIsfoTPjUN8s8Tjh5hWOHX3zF4/q2vNbTPEGpoP3hj2A6d4exEv4WWWJ5znAz93YxIYg/KSIkBauIKV9eob5zn6bmHw6KrCZlipDgtkSuub1TjTk/EfhuT1LvUW0F@3VOAT2iNydu0epfyIk6KwRiK717Eza0sLUTl2DqLpvUlONaK@H29UcTnPVP17UZyyXl2Ak@P8al4t5qmoGLeWBVT2TQQD5x6pjJzrsDAwuISKWHCNwBeLs2sMUKlHD@UO1q5e2/ioEVfSNmJrx9bV8zB26/rDn4cs/ruk4xz292UbbX0eu7em7JJ/tizy0KT5dln2vUbe35OdhK2BRZu@r2Zv4miLgusrdk85KYv42FPVBo7@kqWAHG7Q1WAwn5yMdbWzv2jaX0PCOP3kne9awY/qNFH3NgZr6VmdnDU@t1NTU853xn1zuYJKs1b13AuGKVGzIhdlZdV89uIjKPribEWqFVvt/K75eq80b1DVfgtPhftoRYJkvKsRGXn7QqnCJr9a4TrIM1PWw5ZM28MHVipXv34gpYcDZWd9oKP9VnHIm/79yEB7K5DjHoGdmV3nNwHp1HWvN@4K1IL@0x9UW7W59LETNYXyoYKk5SWYa2h2@GJ9qUi4J7g@owXKTHMZpfQfanwwT45ukrtjlmUINg3DEuRsW1F2foXiDc0ev2KWpnOr9kv/ocblvEkOGkySuw@fCEkFic2HfjS46nPrjAX9XjY8dNBDJF0teQM8tcObr1Gm@M2dTxorfKbsWgOg6rAgmXK4cT3pAnZm3zelej0NR1qf@cBGv87mFpdbq0ymjM1hOXnaMeH2xGcpbnUdZ95ypB5bJp8bFyybMjCLacTe1uxS/d6vOEfjI4AuDzY/f5t@GY9Oaxyxy01r7aHqPJ6gDu57zQGNbHOghcc1z98m2fo@P/WW3Vj/wvqbrq/jNm3T2tuhG1PjrqD0wIWXYA5bq@jMm7zLQ7ASUMPay7Ir7yw1q8B9k3vLjgBMZWs7bTZl2CjnXv32sb3JxV/f3WuB1MNXDoeaXNSsNxenOM0u2wCcQ/N57GIA5gtBfxwhj698wD3k1De4ILc@4@Y96SFvEOZ637jkOtSOx5sdFV/E8S2E82EDgKN3Hv4hGfH0QD0Z1eTpL57bxTc7/nQP2DW2UuBQbzHt@gfd0hfvsjLRhuThH3CpAjPktIEs2ygp6fVUnBD28jSRCZC2En/tkpjW7sFLafsbn9Sl8yG9s7JOUrOzrEE9jdfRPLVtKCZdmhx5xdqNARPfXmLwvZm3i0gx14xm1qh2RcFsFRlPio@zOVl4ZNCRbOxYLizhKxJFNVPjRYMUUqq3ib0tfkzGhRNeq85IcfOK@41R1e8gLFaSFVkxXE8C3s@m5b7BRpV0P3Gobk/DTzBOga31B2cefvIV2PZ2OJdw1q5t6vUx2RIA/M14hSR/DeF@YoyNvgRwI5YfrDZTiIeyeUfmrF6y2xccDWPHYXP0edazNLenbnbvc8uuSW@RuPRqbTxjN5sfT@l5teHGQwnde0WfZ8FpvYefcHtZ8trbwT1b/uA@WRYFHOxPZ@6zsKkLqgcfhdOBdZeTm6q3NPADR7mZDyFxwSLpNQEcOSW9WBeae8M1neRODXOwszq@FjH59BQ3NKYct/JVuag3iyp34WsiXa50RLsnheCwMPL3wvguEyQI6aDY5AwcF3D4niMOpqcnO/RuWJUzbMwPvWS9iYULI3o3DdddmNrNH24g4mrSurcEDkGLzz2MGrNtzBHffNoc9dIUDIDLVFNvto2TIpFjCyqDc@p1wCniGJN8L/CBv02DfFWGS7fMo/kOZWyelsmKXjwtziOKXW0senHIOMRtta4yL4PjysiSHNdJqjoLtsyCF6YpF0VBhReeevwsVx@K3teb3mOzMbjP0MQDwEvWy0TTmYX1B@boigcr@JIKN0@jXl5gqZr6WRt6e9B0G@OlMKNMDPXijMDqOjS1CRPt/tUseg21OvFCdtriS1vjUBe2CzS82BG8uEkHcLZLnnCV6x@8gdZluPEG9CluJLTNtwbjFUA6D1RkDEGuXdxeFllR03BcObtVuaMLk0OZXW/i9eKsxcVxFUrgku@GNuViNKXS1JzsNXgCHT6symqhoRg31DfMKDS/RRzzHJxc3pGXq@BqMLMwNT4XdJo4zEEN2lcdDw4bklN/1Auyrbouh3@asy3hc/IK2N0j6Mm/uSvfO1fWa92URyG33CFMh@EwGy7NVL2XZ/6p93mgWrt7qALyHVnjZpnFPAmssCU0aBizuhOB74VPzwpfYO5y7dm8y1gxP0x5bsoyNOk22BzKwfh8zjNheoQ2pfDN/6xOuzx0ZB9yIVtJs3Hg/Mn7CAxTzPP4dl/WjWeG3MTr57hy/VLIkmlzd/Co2LYMI1e1@ybJaV6eLiSH9c60pp2iOanYdWi4cNuDpxUnqHkvRyHWHdWifGNEwfnQqoMOLa3qvHiY6SSX7xg@ssieG1mlKiuPbMln1S2mzQJaTYg5t8TDJdDm/Xm4As5c8Cn7cNxuya9Z1oU2eVOonFWnQdtiZmitYVgJiMta7myplQ002lZZWf@dca0hWV9qHLYuZ67i8doMvcoCzaaHg1ieZMM5FOX4j@6@/pHsdl6aZR3jx2izeg0NlegDOzKPjdHYW2bRi9tuYFjeFDd9oIprxWVw1kdLrlq4oT7l8lgirb/Q4aphT7ZPDGBALs4gaV3PNt86q0eVnvHiGBCGl1iXCwZiywyujlXzsHNpga3X4IWR7IOCpVcAXmlgkXe5oC1ENF6aL9OOjLc8vjtXC1d1vBx0F8PY2oYgQs3n7a@qtDJ0SrH8yT42pwNSNt4CDMP1lRnk79B2CLNsMzXEl3voYsj42ZSzktiWJ9jbjZtVnu5JZvmqmWaBu1p5RJf3ejm4WVzs7ucK@aVp3u7gPzrbtaL467hfoXIteEz8jRVzyT2JOmWbJy7iJ7KvlNce1xUumHjrrujfdanz8op1OUzbHMYtz@e@Sj7z3fxUOK2l3R5KGGWsmA17PhNoVxaqX8ewgY5yZEuSmGCVSM1bdqW5DVlYEvOTO3f60OQ44gVyOZLYydiVeawEZipGoNSniNpVtDxn@L2FozpZArcrvlcCLR5hLQTYMXgjoTyg3ip/wIeRMxHZCxdiNJ9QDuXszJjXHcsOdb2LqaNKKJtLGwJtmnIhdu4Oba60cqpQTPK3kMYRb7CtXAWeGR2q19CCL6ed7t4WoQdT7eCnxmVO@vCZJEz/98Ogns7AMuBbVhShllHHMxLvMb6GF@XEbyHv25fT1dn5OcpWKcSwExQlbBtzLYmW52wIaPaeaqpVb5tk497u2dYjtV7OXf3q1fwME/CybugBle5lGCdLspE3dYdNsrVhN5PbHrXauziPPtJzL5vAWnHue7@Gyd6VDCYxMpmG3uGmGifsshdNhaisf9Rtm9AuxlQ7u@WsarVd7LV4NCXpSmljqJVn/Yzhd@eao2V/UM5/yz3DVixl3cmpDuzfkyjrH8izH8GmfN8m@BWk4UX2BKE822Ft9dY@/gAIFIzeQUs3LbpGTC@H7eHrTtKNyNQ/d7ctmdjXzhYLivEmY9K/5PbUtj1psKF/ZHtiSVsarlakzLBtXWWX6LgAVn9eZRkEwl9Md92APgUzC@q/Rcdi9cl2T1SrFTHZxz2WWcsbwvQ2Mzq2feul26kdGwp9HLWEs5@ty41aWluxlpx2tWP55dTOCX4G/R8OcD5RpzJYsNBJluwcuGPqWC9C2GDK3UXfKpKMxCkV57mmcigrXENgu61soOm2o7xw0H69qTqK5lV71trOKELy50wQj1chGylbKi5yZTwLab4Qn@jYeiLpn2gzqm15712YsRXRSXaWy8X2HJ90XbA7LS/Vki4TnWM03V011fXp/MxE5fWS8aQep76/6cwSqO1OPIDNzla51cdy2l@4XwmwlAfg2akuFlcx3LzPjWeLQkfJbcQtRD2UZUnw/ZRhxKLu3HjAsKrO1uHbeugAoIPiOs5VB9tJWYutGa8kmR6ZMwcs9r/Y0OXCdo77bhIxukt7ujrkFUDQtxHfs6UdXz8IbIeji6LmcmPylNWgYx0k6la0UeleY4eIp2GzymhHbS4QluJaOflagLsblhHJKFoRpYtG@V@3jJPeDb6MG3rI4ld7a3Vqnmdr//esyTZs5znLprjD1943qMGHHaRZ3crnAcHT4T9ysbsMTf/nPchUXBmoctrmpbbj@@l6YCMIz@rFCbMvOHS1c2TN3Yi2XV7ST/8C)

### Explanation

Uses two different methods and picks the one with the shortest output.

Method 1: Convert the input from base 8 to base 256
Method 2: Repeatedly finds the 8 most common sublists of length 2 and replaces them with an integer between 8 and 255. The dictionary is stored at the beginning of the output.

The first byte of the output indicates the method used.

Input to compressor is a string of Malbolge. Output is a list of integers between 0 and 255. This could easily be encoded in Jelly’s code page if preferred. Input and output to/from decompressor mirror the compressor.

Answer (score 1):

### Retina, 47.25%

**I know this is currently uninteresting, but this is still a WIP.**

Cheap algorithm to compress Malbolge programs.

```
ooooooooo
a
oooooooo
b
ooooooo
c
oooooo
d
ooooo
e
oooo
f
ooo
g
j\*
h
jah
k
```

Decompressor:

```
a
ooooooooo
b
oooooooo
c
ooooooo
d
oooooo
e
ooooo
f
oooo
g
ooo
h
j\*
k
jah
```

### Explanation

This simply shortens the source by replacing the o's, after noticing that there are too many o's in the Malbolge program. [Try compressor online!](https://tio.run/##7V3bkuMmEH33p/gt7/spedkkm2RIVVClUvn9yYwt68bt9A15TE@qsrKAFojDobuh0T8//n37@/tP7@/x8Xf5flkuf3lcXn6dry6/3S8uP27/Xn7//OfyxyX8fL38eQnf/7z89f7@Fgt/nwlv0@3y2@bufzHEb59/HxmuSeGpKC73F8L9f1MMc/F4nS8/Hjxfflbhcff263j3djmFtQ7L3fnydr1muG5/bErMOadd6jXG7bOPqY@aT4@7U7g/OIY5e5iFhnvhpUZrvs39a0zq1rpxzWYBbn2@sm01stUN16lQcC756Mhp16@P4ov4uM/w8Xt@PJhvrt8Cmyn/tEflF2lxKjx1qqXPGVaQToenTdtXFvcZjm27vcJCljnPZjRMtWZtHrh/A0mzsunrcHk8bdPK5Wlxn/Ao/WhGJimuY3YRvLaq2IxNL@3F5qSm9@8pYfsjbca2IpnSufu36@0PQhs2rzcjNXv/Prx2P@uI3mbMd30mfXf/Np6PN9YnTumTbr8PMEiSDvfvrJHeyqJ51/q8tML9mZxyN6GXeMtckpy//@DD/O0EgJvkwivcJKYpC/uWEspY3GZ84GRq5omVmaOcVGz2nGWP00Ods69kVzCT@pEcivfRvl@bUBlImXy59HkYFVMayN@9z@wUUs98yxEWXSqkNyAWWwsk9djXPJcxLmP@UONQSzqK39en0HGNB26zhL0GE3K3yoAJqS5VELxPOqQF@GZVzCHxmBpKt9N3G/Ja4pEoqtmOasShFpmE3PvNZGw@IslwzBHKCanWmc2YwT9aYNEgpkKdkoQa/grPOjJWI@NRV0rrFKdCX@3AkH1Ghq8aeROLJORuNSkrh84CaZWzlqym9Oc6g6czd4ylFsd0fMRUV4OKLPMstWimtZKizcI5HWmC21jsbJKoWFQ8BKIIZbN64kTq59o7gETVBwRTFKFsQVc2KZLOX1sFky8txtQzUawxlHFhbaxAs2EkGavVgDRHMWNmPB6aQZEx35vA2gEZcywBFMyoTdSCqwmFtUUtY5kekq4hyDqM36lZy2ZGRBEABMWWKUoXtLsXJqCdpUw1zm8UrrM8XPgzR6h0Vi21XPtyKezJu1xxitUaVtMrdayUQ5@/zxfrb7KanlgB1fypOx/N/xjWjZqC7zRTZ/xtEXIiNW7VOe3/CNZhHVh4meXO1K53nLjvOhL6nJgXq3mj7vl3jtXk@NbJ9YcwE0VYj3Q8MPLjLeGNgcgeCdz2gNiSjg0WalglCD2klXepy11fIxcrrKFg1WIOe8ngZ3cN7YU36WCqto335pmlSD2mMZTg3nvYupzS2YUhUg9GkkpIK18ddoKuzP/ROpgso6Ydy2Q3rUzVZ8CyyECiSxG3VxdBLGmBgLuggK8wadaxUobU/0GlnwOvB5ilKIwRVLghqLJAYI33QBzZQWkMB@74EpQj9rBWH7P7hV2O3KN6fSroHUFJcs/q9a2glwQlGT2s2ceivhKVZfS0Zl@L@kxUltXjRA8N@g5kPSgszUIA3YNMlCKrOVSaiQArDIj7UVyejQWqSU94J/JeVpEgQItt6dTVkV1D1XhAW4oAPiiEMMigDgFVaYAUIQwa1IO3BgOUsjxEjhBBJBqSyat635iiMDliEMmcklSJCUPBL0wPVXJcQciSSqJjShFVGriylpF4cQgvShNNGngylqGkGOijTAcj9lJ0W8aRpgIQTeLqCDhlyGnBBZw6CZoTg/TM5FPkKYFTy5Fgjh91eWqIlG8bkjwhHfb6kmkS1ZDJcmpoPYGjC5pBVROssm0tfNkWbefLVASpynYa/jOkBGCDV13E9pOW0aJY2pMldHXBa6cBGILLSKoyzHpoBtb6gSmOtZHcUV7GKhCZW2ATjgnX0PX6duTUst9qd3G9HYD10eqPlsv/uR8INT9wt8Xr@Kyl1Obi/t9DmqTQ2vq3TEeG/akfvXuj3jP39maanml15p2vrYd6dyer9NTNg@De3XZKtgWx8rgkU6E/j8NtfgX3c06Wzt78Wl//PtNzgiDpAyCNgQFbKBxHbPHZVWSk@QABO9Rs0LEDRx4bXwMaeTbcvIdyJyKYqZdnwSBXYztKeFFG4Pc@Cwa5MgBNyBDCowkyXl6YFRr8W6NYGS4irL2okUjmAiheL3kEjJOJHpkw9RBdNimjqYBgnpQtjobAUHt4ElFIpyIJ5HjabUUzRRVbiM9Gnca6azksC1qMnSYLkSzisYxkDu9UfUokxJwAoLyXBZ/PGPqyU00fqnnyiYrgdxmAemhaUIVCtKcoK68driu7MX4mtZyAmDbdNOgFKjmIbd7yl5YJpYwiCoLOn6mKTNRYIBTpy85DqjzUk4VA7ye@vEzB03geQly3IXoGz56/hDiqLFhCk5jTjrUTx8gKL@OGRFbNSev1FR6iBdXLEFfRaxoGI8HD3gKKc8oJJpWBOkNcyYrN1pNxNZZyU7rd9nUosY6dYiPCUN1/WGYj56Guuo2yE4en3JCnq9emGCHJmHr/NLUagXoD@3xSADnBdPfZ6BtRPPBkFzKJk9IAu3EIfFPDkZHnTwYdzm4vAqJhTDkL6W4QPGMiA8YNBnjarPWSGg@PdXh0c5LzD@BXWmCLb8Hpquuc4gRkLDhpBcWMpPRgAREE9QeF1ZPgi7r6ydxb6nzUnY96IUawSEGLsHn9fclMMiqiwkQvMl09565WcCJtnJh0iak3oMTrFJxYGteNyGFTZHP@pPmNN5VxFW0nHn0/UCfaQReEFTXoIQMjTqSh00Clt/TuURVPHRtqZZfJ9WlOXE4cee8PSFCNrTEmW1fV9qyC0aK5OhKmOyei88K7jJY6oK2GkqB1t8gA3rHkHCMESY53ooHLWafrNvkeCg/lGDAK8wxINkw7rLBPwm4nvYFFzwtIdv/P0@5GVKei2gIqPE3B8HH2wdlHjYZOIyEJpJyKvsSWRLtwdt6hLMXTWchAGsYUq@o/qvE65icfMM4@aAPEyaWPcfUMB4DV9JoSRgYKU@/EI93wwkSHmrvP@cSUT3opJ9qwGdchTFyKqplMWhCyOFmQGW6za17t8ALnlX7HYFjvYmfF1@RHBBxxM8TJXmx/jKkbxmLpm36wF1u5ce3mnBh10@9W6cJmtBMwCDoNn2I6gkYngIYf0ee00jWK@Om2@bW3yYI7RQc8oB2mICWtp6MnR3njKMJNTkpnhV4ZrYArHDY46Aq4GvHY8IsJw9DD9chmlTPMCVHneh8qYgcD8@3vIUgGWJtqHlhuNzEZfhoWDx/0sIWvEMtpaWBRFxqouBnhXC@OnzirEJphR39Rk4MaDD3OMiafFv5Sa1W8AJdRFqd4699MfeasOF8qvQi1YWcdCy9Nh2BM0eEmCha3773BvmMu9d30DwsnLn/CK@x87DlJdSUpy0AqRXt@8CV1i72ChmrTOUcMEtTsApiceyyczM8TUa7yeYDh4h@k@wY1bLTTpjIF7oFDaJx@9FWfM8lH4wM3zjd6h1fIfNFfQAMq4IpgfjkFneMiMjuxa89CEN0cMnuAFpOAdDSfTnu/anqPqBQKH6ebzgaX5ck5bfyoxNW86Gq7@IRAZY7RnpwK25Yw5w0BQM4unV3Jxl@lAcDCpRc/eZS74tVn1avXoUoNgKGlgM0bzkhdPTxdTgrEYNQITa6Dyb8eYW1w2W@ORxxUjY1AtGnOaUd7U/NTTF503EDIGXSHIef0dRl2Tgk65qo@Leu@wEFOPWbU09u7I9Cc6@7oLXScfJCoCj4LAXuaLSPTC6f6Q0Y9y7p3/jmLf3p@Px0z24FyGUgN@Tks4bchDEFleloyBh/yVtQXYJ66MRqnDoczWZ/qZToPvepclGd5eOrBoUP9aKfhOgQXL00BL60Ig1@p1AWGGoMAe4gZCwcj2tA6Mwmx1y1XjRAEoPvQi3h46bmjOYWIUWF5Rh9p6HM54LWjm9rqg4gkFNHR@B4VhARJKK5PAE3yMJkQuMNZhAA3GEQGAwgQsgtTNB20zyTH6cFthIm7vG81JYiRoeVv8DmDGSKqAYjGNjk4HGPwza5txVDDhBQDRc28ILukyRuDhrAglF0MjE48YZGCF4zjswTlYDaOWqFIDvwFCxZBDDSNKE0kOGB0cNL4@ptykMQLzx2gSaqx6nkSTERuC1Kog08pxNhs8/7X9miTtwKOFA7Tzb/1FNBScodRo2DcA8bRUWC7Rg8mZP2Evjjiri9G/yNEoYkBPfUDJAdfL9djBU0wdNJFiIaOL6wbzyYaDjHR9guUPHzuAL8KSGONPtH7SnqFmyU6zg4UI5oaRt0yqUxIMr3T7RBLeFidxikv2oaLTyiMr/ZYUgX@zVNQ8WkDw40Ra1SoLbaiICD0vlsZmtt1Tpg5msf@tLXfRsk9XnzK0Fxj1TwLHovmoMd/DBbv0StWkLqRp4@Pk7qLh8QdbosYrssrMwrv4z6go40AGZ9vSJv/DGYWub7RPqeJqKG6oYJEGXYEi6oiwlBF3WSR0obdBKIyaaBU4dMFuNgRqbqt7qmQlGUxfJJww0QjJrErXlqGSfGAXVzNqApwC@WqTSuX/wE)

Comment: I think you can possibly do better by replacing first oo with a, then aa with b, then bb with c and so on (or, possibly but very unlikely, the same but for runs of three)

Comment: For some reason I actually got the compression ratio really high.

Answer (score 1):

[This code](https://tio.run/##7V1bj9u4FX73rxAMFJgxBtm2@xYkb/vYt/atKAbOxNlYGJuC7V1gE@S3p5JvoiRezpXyWJyiG4uXI14@fjyH5KGqvw5fzfbXnz/Xm8rsDsXv39bVU/Hp2z@fitdvm@Xsy85sii9/bF8Oxrzui3Oqark7rJevs9mL2WzM9vl1/WlffCy@z4p5I2D@vnho/n1XR1e71X7/dJT77vPqEvD4VNRp69fUSYuH@l8rafNkp6wTNkVphDb/WimPj1bS2Y/Z7OdhtT88vyz3q6ZE/519mq@N6@/P@v9NzLo6Pn5oY9Z/mtJ8aP7qBItB7sol75eysp7mT97Xir7V@1eWp/9UpjxnN4vzz/rF559NES6hx6d@6PFnVbZluIaefx5/twkW9oOV45yy6sQujLHf3Y@9lLy6hFanFm7Cq/O/J6HlKfO1RG06K3xhBmWLBSycSQBBTZPZxXAWt1xUnozGhlLZwVWd@Zz9Kt50E9TP59cD053Ld4VN5X7bpfBXaabyvLUKxZ8TtCCtem@r7CYz3QT9uh2b0JPknMYaDVWoWtYLuy0wqJYzvh0ul7dZtby@zXQjLrkv1XBEmXbMXgW3tfJWw@qlrliX1GH4Kaa0H4bVsAviyO0KP/62HxB1sJrXIdUZfhpenccwou2E7q53xHfCj@O5H9C@sRq@6fjcg8Egqhd@Yo1hkBPNndq7pXnCz@TkCgQ14jGxT7I7/MKH7uABAK1oTxNakcOYK/v6IvxYtBNecFJF05jAzOGP8lb7nKSL016ZnU3SyeiIraNLbzi079sqBAaSI50r/jyMvDER5Hfa0zmFhBMfU5RXXaocBoBYrM0wKEe35K6E5jrmeyUuQ1F98d3yeDou8kI7SdnVYEpXkB8w5VCX8gjuRvXiSnBgUEwvsh9b@oKHbVu6tcQ@UQST9dWIXikcEa72dSSMvmKQoJ@i9EcMtU5nQgf@oRmuGkTlKdMgIoQ/z7v6jBVJ2NeVhmUylaevOmBwvsPBV5G0A4ukdAVFKcuFTg9p@ZP6rKbhYzuDD2duY3w1NsPxYYa6GijLdZ7FZnXUlpM1mtmlI1XgOno7GyXKeBUPhihEXqeeWKH6OdQGIFHhAUEUhcjr0ZVVsgznL1vBpEszZrgy4S0xKOGVtWEZohVDyWitBkh1BBM6xmOvGhgZ57AKWDpAQhdLADI61CZsxtaEgtVFLKGfHgZdg5DVG79VtJTRhBBFACDIxExRvKBOWFkB6ulLFOL8SOYwy4MzNynKQGeFYv2l9@eCvbmTylQmWMJgfKCMgXzQ93fTmXBLBuMHVkAw/XA5H5r@MqwjJQW2qaPM8NZCpISUOFbmYf8bYBnagQXPcw2p4uU2FbWtDaLPkWlhJY@U3d3msJL0Wx1dfhBmDAvrBo8HQnp4TWhjwJBHArU@QGxxxwYJNaQciB6SSnsty0lfQ2fz7KHAikUc9pzBT@4aXINH6aAK1o3W8sRcqB6TGErg3rvYupTczo0hVA8alEqIyx8cdoyudP/hOhgtI6Qd82RHrUzRd4BloYGEl8KuryyCSNJKBO5KAXyVlWQZA3lQ/V@K9HNJ6wFiLgxjlCLcUIqyQEka7yVyZJdCY7ikji9GPmQPS/UxuV/I@dA9KtenjN5h5ET3rFzfMnqJkZPQw5J9zOorVl5CT0v2NavPWHlJPY5coYG2Aa8HmblJCMCvICOl8EoOyk1EgBYG2P3Izk/GAtakR7QJv5dFJDDQopt7uNTh3EOVeEFcCgM@UAjBIANdEBCVBpDChEGEeuC1gQFKWB5EDhNBKBriyQuuvhFFweSwQcRblMRKHDAUuMHkUMXHFQhZXEl4TAmiSgJX2jIGqziIhpJEkwSelGUIKQbyKJPBiL4U2ZpRpIkARJK4EgJOGHJScAFOnQjNiUB6avIx8oTAKbWQoI4fcXliiOQfG@K8YTjs5SXjJIohk7SoIfUGii6oBlVJsPKOtdBla9SdLlMQpCLHaejv4BKADl5lEZtOmkOLImlPmtCVBa@eBqAILiWpwjBLoRlo6weqOJZGckJ5DquAZW4Bq9CPWJRJfx@vnLqet@r8WBwvwKprXdec/8/pQqjzCztHvPrvuuayfpz@d5HGydTWfu3oyLJ760fq3gj3zKm@jqo7au1o87b2oN7tyPK91XoRuHftTnHWwAReN0jk6c/@cDs3wemek2tnW09t83cT3SYIBn0AiCNgQBcK/RHrfXcQGcN0AAEd1Fjo6IDDjY23AQ03G1rt4O9ECGbC@UkwcJVYjxLulBHovU@CgSsPgCZ4CKHRBBovd8wKEf4NUSwPFwasvYiRiOMHIHs4Zx8wmUzkyISoh8iyiR9NHgTTpNg4mgSG4sMTiUI8FXEgR9NuA5opVLEF8dlUp7HkWg7JgmZjJ8pCKIt4WkYyhXeCa0ooxIwAIPcqC3w@I@jLmWrSUM2NT1SIdZcJUA9OCwpQiPQUpbVqB9eVszE@JrWMgJg43UToBZRzIrZ5bL3UTyh@FGEQNP5M5WWiyAYhS1/OPCTKQylZCLj6Cd9exuBpeiuEcN0GuTI49vzFxFFgwxI0iWXa0V7EUbLC/bhBkVV00rp/hQdpQaUyxEX0mojBiFhhjwElc8oIJpWCOoPcyTLR2qNxNS3lxhccX@sQYh09xYaFofD6oZ@NMg8l1W2EF3Foyg16urpvimGSjOrqn6RWw1BvwGs@QwBlgkm@ZiNvRNHA49zIRE5KEziNg@CbEI6UVv540KGc9kIgGoypzEKyBwTHmMgA4wYGeNysdZcaD411aHQz0uIfgF9xji35CE5SXWeURUDChpOUU8yUlB6YQwRC/YHC6kbwhd39JJ4tzXyUnI9SIYaxSYHzsLn/c8lEMvKiQkUvUt09p@5WUDxtMjHJElNqQLH3KSi@NFk3QrtNoc35keY32lRGVbQz8civAyWiHeiGsKAGPUnHiBFpaDRQyW29Z6@Km/YN1bLL@Po0xS/HTPnsD5CgIkdjVI6uip1ZBXqLusqImO4yEY3n3qW01QE6ashxWs8WGYB3NDlHCUGc651w4Mqsk/SYfAqFB3MNGIZ5Jkg2RDvMc05C7yS9gkVPc0jO6z83expRnIpCG6jgaQoMn8w@cPYRo6HRSIgDqUxFb@JIop47O@1SFu/tLGggTcYUC@o/ov466jcfEO4@iAMkk0sa4@oWLgAL6TU@jEzITT0RjyTDCxEdYst9mU9U@SSVciINm@kuCCO3okImkxSENG4WJLrbdKoXurwg80q6azC0T7GT/GvcIwLscTOJm73I6zGqyzAaW9/4i73Iyk3WbsbxUVf9bpUsbKZ2AwZCp6FTTELQyDjQ0D36Mq0k9SK@uWN@8WOywJOiE7ygHUxBQlpPwpUc4YOjEG7KpDSW65XSDrjAZYMT3QEXIx4dflFhGLy7Htqsygwzgte53IeKyM7AdPt7EiQD2JuKXliuNzEpfhoW7j6Y3Rbegi@npoGF3WjA4mYK93pR1omdCqEaduQ3NSmogaEns4zKp4Xf1F4VzcFlKptTtP1voj4zlp8vll6Y2nBmHY1VmgTOmKzLTQQs7nz2BvYdc@7aTXq3cOT2J3iHnY69TFJJSUrTkUrQnp/4lrrGWUFFtWmcKwYRarYHTJl7NBaZb8ejXOTzAJPzf@CeG5Sw0UabygS4B@xCk@lHXvUZk3wkPnCT@Ubu8greWvQb0IA8uEKYX5mCxlkiUruxq8tCILrpJc4OWkQCktF8Ep39Cuk9rFxQ@GS6SWxwad6cE8ePiF/Nne62s28IFOYY6cnJc2wJtniDAFBml8RLycpfpQGAhUov@eZR6o5Xml2vVJcqRQAGzQU4vJEZKekKT5KbAmEwirgmh8GUvx6hbXDpH46HLFBFDgLhprlMO9KHmm9i8sLjBoSciZ4wpNy@zsPOKE7HVNUnZt17OChTjxr1pF7dYWjO4eVoGzqZfCBeFXQWApxp1vRM99zqDzLqSdZ95p@x@Cfl99NhZjsgnwNSk/wcFvPbEIqgUr0tGQYf9FHUO2CesDFqqgSXM2nf6qU6D93rXORmefDUA4cO9qOdivsQVLxEBdy1Igz8SqUsMMQYBHCGmLBxMEUbWmYmQfa65q4RBAHQc@hePNz13BGdQtio0LyjDzX0qRxw395NcfWBRRKC6Ih8jwqEBI4rbp4AouShMiFQhzMLAdlgYBkMQICglzBZ00H8TnI4PWQboaJu72tNCWxkSK035DmD6CIqAYjIMTmwO8bED7vGFUMJE5INFDHzAr0kjT4YNAkLQniJgdCJI2xS0Jxx8iyBuZiNolYIkgN9w4JEEBOaRoQmEjhgZHAS@fqbsJPEHc8dQJNUYtdzJJiwli1Qrg55SkH6Zqv3v/SKNvoo4JTcYZKtb90EtISWw7BeMHkFjKKjgO0aOZig9RP85khe@iL0P4QoJDEgp34AySHvl8uxgiQYEukiSEMnb6wrzyYSC2Ks4xdQ8shzB/CrgDjWSOO9L6RXZLNEZrEDihFJDSNsmQQmJJ7eme0QTXho3cbJzxqHS55QCF/t0aQK@DdPgYpPHBjZGNFGhdhmKxQEiN7PVobkcZ0RZo7otT9x7TeSs4uXPGVI7rFK3gUP8@bA@39MzN8jla8g9iBPmjVO7CkeFHdkW0RxX16YUWgf9wEutCEgk@cb1OE/hZmFr2/E72lCaqjZUIF4GSYEi6giQlBFs8nCpQ29CURk0oBSRZ4ugJsdBqvbyt4KidkWg08S2TCR8ElMipeYYeK9YBeuZgQFZAtlIU0r89n/ZrMvZlesn4rPy8OyWG@L1faPzWq3PKweDqv94flluV/tH9/Pivqv2q23h4f5f@rwogmfPxXrx2PMa/GxeF1tHxohj3baf60/7Za7v@qAf7@Y3Wp@imxe@br@9LxdblZPxcOL2VS71X5vdnUxVu3TY1Oe@nFjts918v279WG12T@cS9P8XdKuPtcFaDNa5Wj@WpnHdPYrHtqYNv2yftwdTi3y8WMn@1Mx/82Wdkzz2RRbcyg2y8PL1@LwdVWY3fr39Xb5Or@KPDXHl/n3S7Xff/jH3398b9rMKsEvr@/f/fq3H3O7CR9//h8) using standard Python libraries serves as a baseline for other advanced approaches.

Here is the outcomes for common compression algorithms.

```
Test case 0
Library   Score
gzip      50.000%
bz2       64.912%
lzma      87.719%

Test case 1
Library   Score
gzip      3.908%
bz2       2.968%
lzma      3.826%

PPMd      3.161%
```

NOTE: The PPMd algorithm score is obtained manually using 7zip to compress Test Case 1 into a zip file using a dictionary size of 16M and word size of 16 on Windows.

Comment: You can try PPMd aswell, as it's really close to 1%.

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 0.00116%

[Compressor (large test case)](https://tio.run/##7V15d9vGtf//fQpRiUwtMYeiKGthqcWUImuXuy@nr/tidAHadN@OLLdu0jZ9raW2ahKncZSmcdKmlRVFcmP3nUPYyTnOOTh6X8FfJO/eOwOuADEDDEjHhC2CwOzL7/7uvTMA@MTXP/fEV7/0xHvvsf9i8GeY4h975ypcmsagZRmD7N4VvKBwZx@TWYY5aFqGBRHODQwYZM4BfDsH71w1JQ/MeYOXypxDXvU7V5033HiowDk0oSJnHxK8SWW7/yHatJxDagVEGxZkvMGcIypOhPKcJoYfYzgGYZSJwZUzqAdTGewEe8HTmNVEZl0qdoIlQV370DJo5CAUYrGTW9i2Q2oFpL7ATm7TCDlvOjfuXbl3xTnAD/7Hb2xRNaTy/5j931ZNF5mzjW22mLNDoTjMu9W6oTUGc27SBDFnj@rHKIreZ851jDk5xg5gK9j9p17ANDvOHnwOLWcPBg9Kvv/kr3idu3D6NJ7uu/8h4HkM2IbYQyxh6yJcntzAbvEB3oHCsS/bNB1Q7jEk2uJDQRkuwTn2H05/jsF7prNjYhtE5Vu/oGmBacKLy5TTYj2iGSxV6RXrxapFb@or34WB3BaIoCY8wjt0WE1GES5UoHKCyqM0HCbrq3QKCxNFmdXzasGnqDcwUmkCGZTRz0MO2AD1rge6MVRXXLVte/WtOWaP8QHpY6exNJjBDPXWYFne/iM2TCc4LTmBCzYCJzCWOJx5yu/s9LBRLABk6QwVAG0YoxJ32Dh8Wwab4LOIczhJQ2uwAi8H@lKkLmAlU9jy2yk2zauFyZuh1Babxe@b0D9AS6/BzuLlLuQt8Qr32Bx1GuA7j@U@9QLUtt3vbI@4fX0cE15PsQVq2MFEHzuHOW71skU@1ztsiU5MtkytQOit8MHdZqsCBmyNKsbOr8NZH6B/gwbBGmPnqUMXi8PFAWg5DvpKytmfm8fkF9PDOGZPPg3HmRGIQRCwD/IxPXa2IUVuuFiagegc9Ovg5HYB@lDMOQf9CIIRTJVnH4L0mQk@hziWw0UoccbZHlgxGlKzD0PSEUzjHKWh0KmZKV4/Fp1xwZGmHJT@I9SvAeeoWOKtH5hOzUGheciW7k8ThI6hJ9iDi5CQfRTH8YyzP2Y4h4MTfWdSE4aJhyGQKDxxDlGaPkZjcgmyDcDn5DZ2G@TT2b53ZbIEI3uUL@HwYAIYBDcFtI99nBqEbZ/BgcQOOrvYmntX@vMjzrE7nBehzaU8DAL7BLUoBYMDmBbfp52dUXG@Pzjh7AxBVz8J6c47162TW/zoXN@APzjvo5A@DBkHrOGBfapCd9BJZ88Yr73oeedqIUPHUfZpSDhKFxgPfc8YY6kCHWBE8FuEs/@GlFDMXMYY/zTRkChKxP93bdrPQNqUMT/gjvswjEF6huYBZm2ahiXfP4CTg9z4WRxujDpOE@ogQzE/MCcgs2JwLE5BKexzCJCT21kEzjqM6dTnaA5ADgm7287utLOPsQgAPuzs85AnByXPYIKB6ew8FLY@jI0rzqxOQXsykH4dErAv0LDNYqcmoB/OgZXCb5gIECtnP4NKooefFoYglH0RMpyBFAWeYq/QcIJxMI5QUPW6wL4EuaYQRjlo4qWVFEB2awvH6smnJ@GDMfCVTrsIc3YRYOzL2Pdp3nXA9i6MV44kMEfgH1lJFeYxgH0FEmJIDgf15DaMHw3QRRTmdBpjptJfGcbhoQv2VZxamDxoHPQ9i5@h08BYcLIMYUOj4iRlfZF9jXiDMxVKIYm4s/0RFPDChLP/YeQFFE4UdPZ1ItCBla/np3D0gSKmSU5IjrF@mJ/VD2Epj7JvQNrPY6IREtmti9B6bDFH0SVxhtM7j6Pipkizb1Il/VztCOIkUSUtcrRa5OO4gsRA4znSz74FeTZQ6NdAcOjTYzo36TB6Hr5Obo2u9bBvQ6ox5@YCfDDtwtjJLRBN/FqYhZTugT1BJsOthSdObvHZhkC4XIJY@GDOJbyED/sOChwyUI9hwpByLlrmjAQc0tNHp@y7kGy57@xy36IBn3euWs7NXjoKXQLnGMq@j4oKZB6lHxvPj0Oj@E2Nhcbwc/YDkrLnM4WCRV8QSWfmGXNwAspEkNL1l9gPSQ4MK@UcniEAIPArl1loRrbSFPYjbh0hta0K7s7hTM18g1h4Bk7zXDkQbjCM/RjylHCOpjPYawNtEyHu/TkxjT8u9bOfQLp0/yopEk4maSBOIhKOYwAUwQFiPgpSAwrupwhmoMQsHLI4GHTA6cviMPDDLPsZJCMCGeCqjASEmAqZIs1pisSpxN5GC5vqQ07PiPpQO1CV6XVUgM52utpH6DIokL@T9oe5GicQ4Mki/2CTevkXSVovc57lJJgmKlslGkB1urWVm8TRG17nMYhyqA0JYe4Uu7/5DFnee2NA7s7ecp97hke01naMsTFjFmiavY1eyJyRNciS3e@DRLOm@faVwXFiPGvc2UETfBDKfJ4sCagAqYZkTQi6IHSof7hI5gInrQFo6DzkexnyTfNs68gu/TnO6lVSR60PjDSHQwgZXhAVZeaFMHNSph4625zmabKFssBpgmzXuJ21eU3kgjmDPMB/c/PEh6BtiO1HkCzYu5dJx42nTDSgSJlaeHUOzc590H3Q4iEo9V8o7Ej9eEA1dn70NE/dIwIyVgrs6FSG3SWP4MAC6T3sOwcSO9E7YXKlPXsO/5YMKBBdjOE82QLQylVEhyBvGAXsTgnRRX3Oz7C7V8iwO80lsZcrVtLqKGp4GPrUEAo0CfsBu3OZG4CHG27aO5d/4Fwfw8TIV3DEdBb/vs7uomO1PiWMPBybvfmKNVLVDM726rTQnzhHb6PvOJ3CkNX1/lUi5ynM8PabNME0ux9EdY79ZHc2OeQtkw7UAPhehGbf7MXD6Hn4AnKF4dnl5LomyHUNmrk2tmiZEANpFs2NXnMDpQaS/hmSZoE@12AU8AMUbSFDw2FtY@3bUM8aJrq/@RwKKhcUaP0UKgBum5mPrIJCIOBytYNCViI0oatunCKFgfE4IJtXAaMgepNkW6aLWA5kwJnKAWdBphdRhRcptIh1QIiz9xhqL56HUMvjpzA@@zhkQrfUOVon2aahpjOYiMfR1p1Es5IiciXKQhYnZEMvth/FDA0kMoSK7sRdyuWmM/NpVxXmeSB7F8dhrjKL0N13n1ulodirDewfEKWSxXqRZPLnL3IeIkHCZGT6k@EveG84B2K8C9JGZhy7e417EqAczpGLvD8HFJNy9nBSM3h2SGJ3ug9joTv/hvRD3IKECx4NceMgq8Z4ygCIgyyiMIGc4YgNklDefWHItTqxKi7Kd7d7UvzsNLvzS@xzodCTEmqKqyfUatUgUGNo6LC7/@FeD@Fe@AdkI6D/ks/D0BADDQi9QwSGtMLuHgtP6lKJmG5rS3DiCLenKm7B7srcKQhe5UrpDi4ApHkhxTsX0zTgmK6UxkkxH0GC3HaOALFFIvkiK@O4cnsYuJ@3sOJswDQN50TDRHUGwSDHyi@Sbj0QXgv3hcj3mKooLfSqZlYHUMOxMq2AHIHBTRUjbN3M867nNEAGaR5prLyHxQyw8ksoAWRl5nh6tKJxMH4Kig80Ro6rDFFA@SXn6BOs/FeyTN0y0@W/TpFFOE8OaB5xNUDeHpnkMAaoUbiVK5ogyHSAax1qZPllnC/SGTRfrPw3dDhJd/PuOtvrnNpylEfQ2xQ5iCOQuvwKZFhNU2T5FXJ7c7kZ6sBKxjWe08M0GjOsjAtEA9RCmJ4iqkbXfsChparK11FPr5Avysqv0ghzsctz7cYbMi86xm0IGNxX8/l@7m6z8muUqyTmJcczkcdc7OduwbHoYfk18izBUimjyTFfsWYGyn8fLvF6sTvTpGdBEedFGPaQOW9xiS9VfXaemeNkQNje03POWyscUGAPlV8XPkYJp2zzZWGZ5dZn1mH2CqS3y68PI9BnAJP/RALnMwIUC6NW/ifaAdxWyKMdlqapOuCTzcqojAeAdcr/IptsCkpBk@yz6AQCHc@A8fjuZczLyrikuj68yrXXbnmfWx5pPiQklVD0V0eEYcLKN7jol2@kcWj6SyMVu2a4tD4zgIbfnKC6qWFWPhAdTSN4sGMlbhGVOL5z5QPAbR7VKZX@Bl8fGk4XcUJzHN5iQki9cDem/Aa3kGB8WPmQlmmQoFKzYIBn@VrkeP3pWsVKT7EyauUxdDSFfZ7Ci/KbmHsNXUzrh5jFKBToi5VxcZfSzGGBS3hS4PyYKh@hJzBKKd@5CplHC6yMLFdAUyTF3V2KwGS11@XjSh6gWFZGe4dI31hKobuIjC9OM@DcjKcy9MXK/yaNAVFZTJot/zuVIb6nROSGotXFygjM8eVzZ6wM2KdzZCibZyxn/xw/9BhnelgZF5CzmBM7hDpmH7LgV/kW10HmmR6hglgZbSCKHC/fPt0nIvrOjBkmfIZGyZ5jZVQOYnic/R9lwcqgz0Z2gwdmwSyjDyv/Lzk/VMsSFcWPUIEhps6YA5@O2WgYZXvsTQzhSwvmGXHOvUFnn74KzEZdARakfdHZ6eE6r@IufhfXcEDbcSB8jNm4ZoxXmVk0AaFr9F3@D9eKYIM6h/bW6b7KypaNC8u9xtjZsUUD/tCB7YXj2VkTLxYNZuNy81iKsqOhTKcwrLMFA4rODNmXPgktZ/YvuBSR2SEWCIGkKjJNegzhDdJ191qJp@hn9mXiml9lstYZk5DrnmWy2M8s/2I2KvNMgaacK@1lBHrDpfBKmf0kAWqiZpG6JNaEflIUPJkXvgUemf0UObhLi/zjWtF3b8@SC@0eT27hwpuN6/zcS7N/ZfFw5/oSJuGHitFO58z@NaSHGPvXzvXlDfEhQ54fYS4xG30NMfs3kBq9QudZ9AcXxWGJ/EP7N5SuUgGzcaMBInBJoM9@WsTiF/RAfA2d5yd92JbfouAvXQA5RcHaREIZ7xGengWzOrFkWGOjp5n9P5gQDasLzuEFEK8PpC58DwyTD@A/84I5eAFS2L8jdYzkeUgzW3GEh7lm20X2RHeOVKV9mbt/zP49FW5wzxg0Bumv3RrFSbr76AugS@3fu0bHMLPRJUqhin9xuMhXXEslV4MX0@S9Q/nla9MZZpNxvU/8lqKNMMMcnJtAQEwsOzfQpoOwPvupErNpWwiHf6FyhEF0zUW8hKHfqVgmzP4DZLD/wBtJBsouru7aV0g3T42AkTDF7WVO7sz@I2RYGEfnHnhtgRw2C78W0OOnAy4K9TD7T3xRxtkX1LJGF7gexU8WDVz5MayzFsomukzGZzLGbGqODhWTGC74@i6QnP1n4iS@ZAecWjmj1Vv7z7WZmP0MSUKW87b9jFglLr@FZPw1aAMJGl8AXQa5fFY4ndDCBWgZfrAnFl7CZ2OBFtUWCHvohBjLG73G9wGtKF8bJEX2bxGh9nO4kobFMPsqF5heY@ns0qKxtGjjgon9J1xC6/nO8sbC8gbICe2o3bR/bj@PFaAoYQH4vWD/kZt3I3c2@7m6J9T9hXNNrzG@aNCCCxzPgnQZ@Bmz/0ITyWz05Ufub74gVinuXsmt4pppiZtKaCgKKwjd5m@SJXaJ2de4QU8ROQA@uEh7fJ26hH4Y0OGAfW0lhQbDFLPRJufUtlzhuur0ZPHLfhYHGiCxRzs0e1kL9ZSzl3FPhk7bv8xylNh7MB0FhPoss18Siyh8iwKFRyx85vOue4CdmM6eSlfjmI2muP0Ld4/BfglLLN9McQ/q7n8yhYqzZKMV3pM6h6tKuFgHxyzXtfbL9pNzBUHDc6AM7b/RLOFi289w6W2W1lOzSJmjdMzCPGeXmP2KaxJPcWedTnCdYWuLz@AkMgP60WnXXeabLWAZ29f59oyzPSXI5i76NpfQsZ7O0sTlhtPr3GXi8vgq7Yj1u2tRuEQEue1XabhObmcq2zT9YgEaWOI1bhbbL@bt18hVfPLpKdcNc3an7W1qK7ht6Bii11YsAm6YjSb4@NlxYhT7BfIc7L8/5mw/mud7EmCkptPY8MfBu7f/gQvRa/YuyDdISt9ZkHj4G0e02v9YfZQvsDH7dc4Ts@6qK9LDrEta4oJThv06r2MFZw7tbvufAhncKdgeTqd5immg1lPO7uqjzjZHirMN3UbLu2cRFSLqktFevgh1YPGTNd6INftfKDpoevf28PWb3h6SyF57H@xn85EStX09zeeJ2TcIGNlx@xWxGAuq8v7mc2bfIvxBEfYNbDI2NL/KbDS6aW9p3D0c3vklAu5v4/bBo9BmXm4Oh/HkBrPR6j4/BDaOOWi/IbaQcSd1tbIhMJknkaDBRHsbmjg1aV@HuX9MAO7@5s69K5Prw/c3tycra7v3N58BiWc2GtyTApBFdxmWQweHdmoyh1F52s8xTkF/jzh6JnO8Wj7zXBRz04XHEVhHAuPEQznCOLOPRb4vZx6zj@9dwb1Y@02@AlykzVAOaV4SF3tm3yRpmnJ3jLDwv3KfhgNuO007J3vmI/ZN8xHwBLPMRiP8gv07Z2doYtY@5PO/u8q3msQGz4jY4XE3o200yO23JvPYV/DCPi4G@luUVKRaFRsvUIENtvkF0@cfRlyw6PQDNaHfM40ao6Mxk@VbnNc/w@AHuhOFspuD4hQqFqfYBDeUrhpD6dQyqm2ohIpTOq8mGKy9qMkhUlp1sYOmWVt3Y6zbcssNtQxesWmI5IYo1OCZKy2qpqsJHzSb2hYUMOiZRCKI7u8xA5prDFo@GUVOdyKtunl1s1eKN@sTmHjrlVGtJjCdaF8FNpZ3bW7jK6WZlk@tVqt4kaAKUquhNqt2yMz6BI19oyH0SSLS1EiD1apbNRXWj0BTtzzjq@Li1lbTy0ptZn2Em9vthkeUWZXZSsHVXvl2o2aW6ov1KrU5nMcYtRfN3ahtiEdur3A6r71Q6EPN8HqU6hnOxavusjWiaxN6T71HfF04yXNjQLVGq7kmum6AQVNUQzhnjeYgTzTX9d67NJ9wQU5egVKDSIn9SvYOd/nQO7gJgDXRPkNYE9kcU2Ffvwh/LNYmdHFiBaYxW2gO/yjfbosk9ThtaLPnkNRl9IiFaMM3XHbuq11oIUge6bzihRj5xgQgv248PVVI68SUwqjYUkZzgBSLVTM0taO@5V4JzYrMN7TYaBXVWHx9e3wmLqDC2iRGvQVjeAX5A8ZotqV8Cq6PaogzpANbFtMQ2Rhr@AU3j63hbSU2EkXLZI1mREMrPCK8xtcjYWAVTQkaUxj@Ec1Wp2dCD/zLZqhYEJZPm5oiWuHPp65GxgpI2GgrNbfJtHzmqg4MnnV48FVA2iaPxPAKCqQsL3T6kJZ/Uj@vqfmyqsGbNbdp@vXYbJYPs9lWk8pS0bOqWT16GyVrYGYvG8mS7qPvZCsVZfoaHhGKUsjraSdaSvPcagykimotECGLUsjrYyvHkqVZf9UamOFLM83mlQnfFkslrLC2XIbAjimVUfUaZLqjMaGHPDZ0Q6UMEWZJtk4ioRdLSGT0MJtUM1ZdKLm@aEvoTw9NU6NQVoP8WoGtDEwoYwhIFGQGuaLqBdWFGZZEP/0SteL8gMytWV46M3/A1H@yWsX6t94/l1zNdalMy2zZwpbxLdrYIp9s/fXpzNYj2TK@yQtomb55OV82vSvWAS2VHFOPNsuPlkJKmRYHtbl5/k3JNlQFSz5PJcQKbrdphR1rU2HOFdPKtTyg7d5jLteSxlFXbr8UZsxIWDfV8RAivXxPwsmAGVoSwvZHEltRZSMUakLlUJghXWkrbeH2mnI2nz0UuWaFFPsowh96atQGPJAOrJZ9CzfyIXMpzZgOUZKePdfXDZPbc2NIaQZNJZNQLX9LsYswld7/1CZYuYxW1nG0sgO9TK11SJelDCT1UiL3Vy@CQpVmKODO0IAvw9LZxhZ5lObf0DLPRrgZCJlLhTEMLdxgaGUBI5S8G4qSbWiSYSOsfEXIpzjDuuY49LyEzqc8o/rmNMLsRMipPLP65jbCLEXIGWKGdc5xpLmKlDfETOuc60hzFilvqBlXXKGRHYNoMxgxdygEqK8gK5YSreVSuUMiIC4MRJ7HyPlDY0HVpVcYk@izrKWECGiJN3fzUofnHqqOCoJLiQAfWQjJQUZ2QUBraRKlRIRBAPXI90YOUJrLkyknIoKUaChaeS1X30IWJVdOZBBFW5RULbGJoaQHTB@qouNKCllRS1LHlEZU6cBV3GU0reIoDJRONOnAU8xlaDIM9KNMD0biL0Vvz8KUpgUgOomrjYDTDDldcJFUnQqWUwjSi618lfI0gVPXQkLs@NFenjZERr9tKEoNzWKvv2S1ErUhM9Sihq4awtiCsUFVJ1ij3dYSvuw4@h6@TI0g1XI7Tfg6ohJAPHjVi9j2leZhRYWynuKErl7wxmcBxAiumErVDLN2WAZx2wex4lg3kttYnodXEMndkuxCY8Sg0dZzeuVU5X6ruhP62Tzxu3rRv/gLoUSFdbd4NdZVyVVzwv@7pUXJVO39BY@JNOrf@tHu2Wg9M7y/Hl336LXHmFd7LzW7dWX51VpTkfTs1k6KZw/MFtU1JfKZz0ZxE0MgfijRbL6qDn99ogcTBE1zIBEXAgPxQqFRYn3rbomM5nQSBdShpgYddeDwxsb7AxrebFgzDv6TKIOZ1vlDwcCrxfFRwkPKCOFnPxQMvPJI0EQ0hISjCWW8PMSsEMC/rSg2Gi5MaetFG4l4nEhkb52zETAJmegjk5B2iF428UeTD4LDlVKLo67AULB4KqJQnYqiQC6cddvCMpU1bKX4rFvVWNutnFAedGTsBLKQkkfcXU5yGN5puaakhJgOAMh7lUVen4WwlxOqaQ/VPOCKSmHdpQuoR80KakEhulVUXKt28rZy4ox3klo6gJhgugmgF6mcXeKbB62X@hOKP4pUENR5TeXLRAEbhJHs5YSHtPJQO1lIcvVTfntZBU/dt0Iob9sorgx2Wn9FxFGLDUspJZbQTtyLODF54f64USKrQKX18Bs8ih5UuxxxLXZNgMOosMIeBJSEUzrgUsVgzijuZJmBvVfGVXcZN37BwWsdmlgnPsMmEoZarx/6s1HCQ221bTQv4oQzbpTV1cNNMRFJJtbVP51WTQTzRnrNpxlACcG0fc1GvxMVDjyeG5mKSqkL7sZR4JtWOIpp5S8adMLc7aWAaGlMJSyk9wbBTigyCbmRA7ya1nooLZ5wrBOObjq0@CfBr2oPtiS34LTV1unIImCIDSddD8V0k9Ej90CEgvkjC6sHBF@qu58h7y1N@KjtfNQuxETYpFB7wubhvy85JBn5oiIWuyjW3fOwuxVhnrRJiEkvMbUbUJH3KcI8S5PYRsqPTSm78x3Sb@FUWVhDOyEe/etAbaId2Q1hjRZ0Vz4Y0UEa6hio9G29J09VPNDPhsbll0W3p8M8l2N2870/kgQVcGtMLLeuartnVfJpUa82Kqi7hIg693hXTFsdUrcaRnloPfHIJHgnTs6JCUFRXu@kBq6Eddp6m3w7DB6V14CpME8Xkk1IP8znPon47qSPwaMP90Bysv7zwN6NqJ2KWm2gSqspafgk7CPPPtpoqGMkFAVSCRW9L25JjO9x9nAvZfF9O4sykLrGFWtp/2h9Xif2Nx@EePdBMEAScmmPc/UgvACslV3jh5Eueky9TTzSNryERIe25b6ET2Llk3YZJ7ph070LwopbUa1cJl0QiuPNgiEft6nrXquXFyS80r7XYMR9F3uo52u8JUL6iZuueLNX6PWYWJdh4tj6Vn@xV2jjJrFuOvOMeqy/W6UXNt32BgwFmyY8xbQRNHoeoAn/RF9CK219iviBu80v@DZZyTtFu/AF7dIUpMnqaeNKjuYbR2W4KSGlTj16FdMOuIaXDXbpDrg24omHX2JhGPXH9ZTdqoRhOvDUub4fKgr9MHB4/7srSEZibyrwheXxKaYYfxpW/vHB5LGF98OznHE6WKobDaq46Yb3eoVZJ/Y0CGPDjv5NzTCokUNPwjKx/LTw@2qvKtwDLt2yORVu/zukPdOp53xV6SWiNZywThyrNG14GDPSy000eNzJvTdyv2Mede2m/Y@FK25/Su@wh8deQlJtJak4H6TS6M93@ZZ6HPcKxmg2deYVgwpmtg@YEu6JY5H5wXmiXMvPA3Td8w9R7xvU4aN1TJVp4B7pR2gS@tFv@nSSfHT8wE3CN/peXhFtLfp9YAH54ErB/UooqDNLRLG9sauehaTopiFx8oBWSALSY/m06d6vVnZPpFyy8Enops0OV5xvzgnGj5bnah7S3fbIbwjUzDG6lZPPbUtyizcKAErYpc1LyTH/Ko0EWMLSS/Lm0bA7Xu3Z9WrXS5UCACabS@LmjYSR2rrC05Y3BcrBKODR5NZgSn49Im6HK/6b42UWqAJuBFJTcwnt6L6p@YFQXuq4kUJOl95hGObt69Gw05GHjsOaPkHevQ8HJdQTG/W0e3UnguXcejm6FjoJ@cg8VRGehSTuaY7zyXSft/pLOfWhvPuEfzrFP@38/XQ5t10inwekuvLnsCL@NkSMoIr1bcly8FG@FfUhYJ7WzqhpteHlTHG/1StWPfSw6iJvlpdWPfLQUf3Rzhj3IcLiJbCAh9oQlvyVSr3A0MYgEvcQh9g46EYfWo8mUZz1OHeNZBAgex@6Lx4eat0RqEIioyLOd/QpiX5YDni4n24KNh8ikYRGdAT8HpUUEqI8ipsogEDyiEUhhBXnSAhIHIZIDoMkQJSXMCOpg@B3ksvTQ@IjWGG39@NSCZGRoWu9IdEZIR8R1QGIgNvkpB/H6PKbXYMNQx0uZGSgaHMvlJeklW8M6goPQvMSQ4hJ7MAmRbiHcRItofJitjBmhUZyCL9hEYogukiNaFIk8oDRg5OAX3/T/JDEQ6w7JF1SHbueHYJJpGULpUcdEpWi@Gx27POve0Vb@VbAbnocpm3rWw8EtDQth6k@BZOsgIWxUaT9Gn0wUbZP1DdHkqWvEPMvQxQ6MaDP/JAkh2S/XB8r6ARDm2wRRUcn2ViPWZvoWBCLdPuFLHkkukPyVwHVWKM9T@9rsisSt0TPYocsRnRaGK09kxYKKZrdmfghccIjrrdxRs8aDJdEoYT41Z44qUL@N08lDZ9gYCTOSNyo0LbZKgsChdlPvAydt@t0QHMEvvYn2PoNyFmPl0Rl6Nxj1fkueLmnOdSf/@iy5z3a9ayg6o087VnjVL2LR4k7El8kxn15zYwS7sd9JBfaFCCT6Bulm/9i0CzR7Y3g9zQpWqiJoyLzlGEbwaLVEAlhiiYuS1TaiE@BaFEaslSRqAvJzQ5T1bbV@1ZIlW0xeSWROCY6nklsK16CHBPfF@zKmxktC0g8lEHdtPLee/8P)

[Decompressor (large test case)](https://tio.run/##jVprVxvX1f7eX6HBlgeBrSMJgQSqBFgimIsQ7v2yeknbtPE07Uyb9u29CxPiOG7dC6KtkhjXNokTEjexwBiI7XQtjR2v5ax1Fu9f0B/J@zx7zwicT2@MzpyZ2fucfb@cyYsvPPvi88@9@Omn5nMGf@F9E94by9td2yrb1tcCe9du2ebPbHPIbvt2267ZvfqT1THberIafkj4e@Zc@De7Njg6Ge7YVnf5Jduq29bBA9u2G91Xrwliv232sInzobG7FdcFcPfiZfyFb6U4WV7hI9t0cTNuN/xj4b5/LGebGeLsGzwd@2H6ZLj3ZHXese3wLqiw29lyBYjAS@lauNHNibQnSLknq3Y3Hy2vILnx0jPceHfMNvkWc9sCHACIt2vG@NS23LJwZJsAOHiQ7i4v21ZlLMdXea42752oEOGuqfnHKmPhJoBOkh5s211ag6Qa2e5Scwz3KeyCF0uvYyOi7Jizg6N2xx8I73iRmG2zv94T1Fheyb54mdB3TOLxum0X42Hn4StJuxG@XQy3j0PiKrjcuG2nD7YIv23sfqYYvmP3B7vLL2dmD@53l674yRn8Jex@uGVb89DP8nK@Tugt05dQyL7Ewf1Tdq0vbI87YKlaPw4CGrq8cNo2iRm7s9iH3@AwxuTBfbsd6GShe/HqpN1fCG/bFmFvm/AD2YXm0l0@b5tZV9RuW@OO3TgBwo/bZl7NplklygdG17Abie7FS7IgNjh6wwu0/76uM2/bRHvfLC6ErWDGW@zzkqeTMx7@ina/zwv/IxxEUvyPKZ4uynrhNdDjZsNbJ23zeGwb0LdLET5jm4S@ResJb@TD9wCbxbwixgNSQX/YBF/KE2yBZlIuHzzwiPeeebLaP2T3yNf5XJbmUwnfxZ3aEJyixR3pFS2ACd/vGhUxt5@yrUd7sOqXGnSEzFRVlnEbunsq4mXTiEFVxGh1Mu5khCgxPzVssIQbhYGNg@gVIr8D86Bd/NGHmUxiGD6Ly8H9YRkzs3g6S7i3TcI5YzcKdCgPYwaio93dDC/WSrb9eN0LnFrnvwS9acKXHbvm2fbAaPgmlFTq7Du1UinhOI8@Sgtw0VFtvWWi@EDLEFpbYutqCeqhlfHMCffwHdHeNNg6E9gN4qbjyeCp8JWMWki4wW250yThN0w6A7scmesuXzgy8@za4/UML@EbuHcShL1hYAArKWyfs63UEJxjStRXzbrU1UQqvD7vlKA7cYLrZqi7dE0AoKvVXB2aFzXZVpa0R0vRo38Kd4@iyjXY06U@rzjjJXzaZsI/nfB5M@MVwn9LCCLYv6GbcCW8Cv1MzyXFHeU6Hf5TFx16uNSvSh7SeHrVzHK92dOzM97sTLgOyw//BT1OJ34xtzg9tzhIoHXjzcE7fjXzeH2xD7/BU5TYXwbP2s3wCvfgFgS8YiBWuvN0YPf5IyEBb/FbnF5kmCAwYd8wECUfpL3wdaINjCY79yDb9o@hirkRyteuyZTgrxvK/lALOkM8q6XD1wbtRoB9YWiTDoFfM9530pjXZDj6Vjeya4RqGYkHi4cxwraTcZRAFAgomeA0QgOh/2WmIZxBsDs8XZTIxcs09SEDWRN7@KcJ/0Et2t2UKGbCbs@Hq3kqoDI0n56qiE@KntUd/wGpIYZO98Y4bHEP3D5eD9fsNtLaFDCJsAaEGm3VsXcQ8j1/oDZKex6ds1t5xH48S4avSnBoGkTLqc6NbLkqHlKt0n8ysMayi1BTScEOOtfH04RdNY7j4Q3IAnC/EA873GM4wM7K0/cRe8K/i@8xtBHv78buYd7ZkZikLzAy7OUn4BKkXUITY@KFQ9v7G/ZDFjtnd84Ftv1559z/IHN/nv/55/yBc@FfCfRX48yeg0ague7S1QxSWILq9/0BOPHk6KwXFIZPEfAvBqaZhIkmw8t2U6W4SXUvRheaa2SehL9sAFu0bzxehxdFA30B0v5zhH9KdUDoP9NPwj/ZzbnF6MfsFY2iuOgiDvMnIy7SF14K7CbDot2cJYQOvYVlTvhL8IXZGf0JraDi0QMGV6LreHB/0G4T@FUDTfsDVHgA8K2q6uel35epLMg@n6VllSdi@7po0iWhRwOpuNZnbqN4TOhXGGoQIkd8PB8cjmcaBTN6IdwFE6nZ1agLTeeGaFw1SVNlSVM0iEfXqwrRT7SXTcGx2/BA8J@WKRxzsuRNwkQGw5e@Efiy@orp8wqnCwhvM96khLxJ//Skzxt1x5cMWUhPUlxIM3LtfOTL0t2lfbsTLp9Kjjgok0A8EZbNyKwXnrdrCQ0HI1CXR85@qREh0slXCXveZBLhEmzNo2y2QVM09wXLtuVSIugS4hJc3x@ZJSvRSGiKlNdaQuSFTFeKvLr92wziofwWM1H0ycCQ5EfQj8wZJqhi5wFYSNgdWbPg@fgNDoOEnSShHpgMNimWNK9iNidYHQSPQaFIMSXWde4bvB4J0o/Xg5rYgj8CnzujQ8IbYeTq3INlebMOEhyGzodOmsGOEZnZl9agztD50GjcnnUYhU8lBSsKzYBNy4WA@6bEvZyEhNTH64TGkkfvO3tF3MgU@Z5Ie8Yp4JEEuFlOIrk5nd0SsUs9hGFqoLNrCG53RsReBbdzdxLjAtcMfkNwryRYtJzOXaOwDmEykZqeni74A6NqDkLRDkx9JeuWJ2DHOY3EhzExjuSdO6x1afMuce4YBnw3lzp4wNxflWjaX2U7Y/dyne18fiI/NC6NDsG36U2dLbfKJarwmlQUYKuNCQZQpzalDyoMuZ0t08jWXcnprU5b9s25Q@L9WVcT/PNYXXyR8G2TQrnbQXGNmrLiTuTQWo1/t5KVVm0CVH1yAZB5gt42malcxBpedz5I9bw630DKcKUhIROajTofCKfIGKnu0k2WxsgSucZEAzuUJBR03s@6kMoEe5fO@6yMq/3MLENcRSofYMSFDy/jNXtvXkST/3gHSPaeiQUO2M6tbFVZnECHN56e0uIpHz2jhLnRLRS51byKKMdVUWgx7ZUlsWmkJCud91RuTJed97Qy1szVVCykS26hTZjboBF03s3n@zWoEetdkxpncQ4uy/1HMibZapCCzib5nXdidWwaKI8rd96RXiKXIyuoE9Ixn25W0uUEod8xadWIdIK22dBaLpeKUznrRrffhUQ7bxPhbaPaSUl3KkUocfnT6nmqcxNlQr9ySC0Q66aJbA5obuetSq/kKGfzkscpt21htEz4t0xFil54BFflc4L8obt8C5aeU0uPVuy8aXe/TqQ3IeBypBUmKcXVkjneXKRPKW@wVEoRbcNUY0haBe09D7VVelKh@UzUU@OON0V41ORSYmcbbtx4SQuFMLZyI5sTZ4z6mta8N@WyJCPeddby52n3D8/TZhWm6gJzwz8mPRv2kuwGBiiGh@eNFlbibcvLkQyHxA3dI7vUTuBxXYwIaI/2jHSGCiMkYpynw7CCY5Fum6lIgsoKWj8ifmS0M9Ig1isUjzw6bJcevmIGCgxqj671iuCANZfkhUfNhKMzFlCPmiaC6S596GjSsRtFWJhXdLxTzKq3JR8AFhBGV2LKWQPnqMkdzTtpzjTxMDNI@nl03ahYciwKKZkJ9ElUexTlcjSwoXmtP7nByg1TU8smwpPVT67Un6xSC0cf9otJS7vsqiUA9ZMrpj967Eq8LCu8mCqihRuXLXl9KOygot5txN2u2ApaYrvxDD1rDO1lVV7kqqSBjbJ0@d2lpqmU5U2ZL7pLN@zGSbbmYxLS1MLlfUUQnxGkG8Y7QS8fk@QBGpbWDx7QdBTLLeuRh3TrOZAhSOvGdeNWvEIAdQb/WD1aiFwqRB1UCs4Vw8ObBbQx/A2fXUDFMcxhYXHh5z4bnaXXBPA1UwBMQY9xFgp4U5gJ/O5Sq8@uzfiLff4ij3cEtIUOsy/wZdDjm8CfgQXs93EYPosLNqHpLRmeKbx6rd7or0sdSGfNfnxXcpXo7As0dlf94eO7plGJG98hDTwrkXGQM811zfp4pmcAtKsHJi6XpbJ/eOHXdrPAepnMYBQS9bpJoi6YXvEd4/BVQBQMg99kf2c3pb/j@qsmKxQyHNUZgaRzavRHvlmVNj8lAUvEs2@0WtxJnkERONo36tNl/JHJM/ybZf3x6JoRl@TA2vTsMEBYWSWiB@nA8VCLq5/dNsPpouOrmxKKd3C6BAKuh6HGfuOTC9i2u3Q9smzmWghxnjWDniLl2YVSrO2MrHpdTlEkcxJB2wXJBrapPIrt5vuFSxqroF0zUUmhlU5OW7noLCNbZspksSCliiDcNHHpUNb6R5NCFCPFbMup3lkuS6Upwbtqah6K2zXWs8kBVPe@//HqAJr9SdSvxaj/o9WsmgEeMe1gnEvGM47sjNa8QsGbhFhlzdeNBg16iPg3C7Pl5ZweBTf0jZzX6jFw7QQrjzeMtIRF6e85mdGfHMPoRVs97rF8y6idbs876aleI3xYOVC@riSyDe2zGdFR4jSkFY9lreKEFqE1l4UaklouqlD@aGCbZzMYMtxbBjmmTfjyCAMPsP5g3P760GECduNwJPQxtWci@r4SZ6TfG2kkx9NyYOfbux6bzDUv0FQOC/xdlR3c7wyPmIGD9XfsFmo9qnPiJ3ISSj/JU6CHoZrV8G@NtJdxjR51m3qbgd/xp5kMwL/hsUy6VArkAueQmT/Sq8n1/jmA/toE6qybCemSRRrDvMrZl/g@5wD9lZlLnp5LznhzPCMIRHu9XTnnU8D90gz7vdaQs4I3JyPFkkjKFGC/MDwke/HgPmTPYxr259No7/njSdAsb/VU7EVG1@kouk4X9FQOl2n2tfEAuJ8bOR9b4BEUf2RGBkRuMjG8wCbtZ8Y2pXrunfZLLtGjzno5qiNqal7wearsp@Z70YGx@KqczWjTEhXc8tWkLSbRg6DefoLNUvMv5CusqltSEB5s6ScHTTf99S@SkuOAfcFEX22ijzZ2L2@bX07DiEqjtv0l0smSHybDDubHJuop4dEZ/sSLJvVcb3A4mjjBDwD7vDQYEm14WBq5yGFaqLg/0morpen8R2ZoPIrTrnCdkzCYq/I9wmJpKmpdfmgqlFpOPsc4DnOwRqIxCRBSicbfmigAhgWgPWdotyU5nLQbpc9M@E6N4vCefeoPjIQvZAU9U3BGeyecCMV0Ce2K06VBR4qm75ucK3EbOhiXFqQRRep6JarDG66c@37PDMWZiYHkWSE3KmXki0OvTaCYAAKcZ41Gb/cwfKdqkcejIpan7A8B@l2DABTFbAlMeeSXlqAzNjGLa6JQqX7HyKmsV/xW79w1obkWDH877RWcaA7YbyO9HXnLlyUZ5HzhKOS3jEINsCr1ikdvgF@SVUosPL5pziKXI0jKaDcX8Yd5Up5Iti8yVGAA8DeMPyJfHjbiq@br@GuE5FzAfd1IibnCs1zhWL/DQJR56R5Xes1LlVkQGF8zajepqO/QTxZ01ap8sKj2WoNmDwK@BcyvGg07wt6IM@r5HPRI5/A86ytGqsVyVQsjdD61qDOSTlBySSvWGXuoL5soXpOPykRFiWakTsc@7ebEd4eE5S@ZdGQO4rNl7a1T89JEC2ArBv2i0dQlblauMs/lNAmUPgOMoAD4LxjpKstRvbfNb7I1NTk3GwsTLQLeRJ9jz7LdKGCyaJKiuIZ0XcxbC8buSIqvGwiWop9H1QFXwmwO5SFD6yzLRPrUDOo/puozhhUVj9Gmjd3kIc8zRoNXkwI4/OA8ZQ62/ncZkxq2EVKq2Fnc4rTppQ@qbRJ7MIFMsBaTODQOOrh0BYRpRVTmQZIglwBNrDFEWMoX01ET8EkRpJHUAjfkZMT4wt@wYTfFHJA38t2a3A9R9NRBjtvKJlk@4levDFbgimmsSMpPYQGfPJ80scYlbdBYkEw2Ak/1fcj9oGGlSSJSFC736TcoRkmuyydk5cSR1aK1/MP50a/3SZQOVMdxUrjjPb1fdB@fagPsmDnY8/j67iGo/zTN8cp9YgQSnR3qmpMEngVSll0w/kDgCR/wIkoBdLC6DCIRU5ZPVrXKherYIG/JfDni7WkCnvpfEhj0hBzVIg2PBOg/eXCZ7LZkeslIUQtugyO7o@X1Y1ZlETQryo@EOa4CBfrUJYxfQ5/vqQFhYbstlGMtn/zCB1Twoi8YryqH/BFS3/AqvPSe9P6RqYMHFIIXsND2zvHB/XhfPIIwZaeDPZTfbdLt@aTHP5zabd5T2QdbxleoQ6CnYISLPZhVZAC48LEKYtccUgaZ@0HPToQ6BbprsCBu@DEM5MkXMSHfU/e3O1hdJndMBPH/GoixbTx2GthI9vUDL1Bpt7mmrIp73xsIAgEEludH/5nPhfc//fT/AA)

[Compressor (small test case)](https://tio.run/##jVnpchvHtf5/nwKgBA1AmmgABEmQMEBSAEVxAUllXyqLkzgxJ05mEifOnqIoW5adODchmIRe5EiGN9qObYimSNmSb9W0aFXJVV28r6AX8f2@cxqg7MqPKxE9Pd2nu8@@9Dz26EOPPfLwY59@av7L4C@M/D9z5zJeo3AwjsNBc3eTLzLuugSLw2gwisMYE@4aBwaN28XT7d65HP0/G@Pe112N29Oj71x27/fmcYDbi3CQ6wLguuzd@4/pKHZ7ggWmwxgLrxm3L9v5UV0ZcfyA4xziVMThfg/nECo0R6RCYaJjoOgzUOaIO@GsLjADkoPYJDZHN4nbnmAB6DVzdEs45K67a3c37266Xf74n09idDzS/39g/nfjPhKNaxPn2LgtGSWbt4/PBjahcTdEQMZ15HxOyXTXuB3OHB2QAGJh7j19hTBbroPfXuw6YB52vnfpGT1zG91n2e32/mPgJQ60MbvHHTbO4/XoGslSBm9hc9LSFnFg3wMAbSgrZMEF9Ek/uk9wuBO5rYg4@MM3nhSxQEx8uSgrY5PyaJh0nyozwKM9NZ89fBuMbHuNEBROKEF7x2Ay0VMVHC6qclLYEZlMnyhu5reKjvvHG58SasCpQJQMe2R1ZNfkhLoUyBj6zHbHuHU@i82BeUAZkjHD3A0SzAu1oSko/vumKB2KpeT1woygA16SnWVZ77ZSZpQbwJbGZAPgMC47bpkKnnFoJlSKlOGksDY0Vd0HtNSEBB5SJ@a30mZKj4XwpgU6NjN83gB90JaB0Jzm6zbWNvTAjmkK0VDfWe779BWc1s669kiP1jME3EmbOUFsdyJjznLFzQEzr7LeMgvSicyiYEHVW1Lmtk3Lq4FZloNJ/Ap6GWj/qjAhHjfnhKDztWItB8zJ9KW06zZnCX4@KJJnl55FOz2CGSqB@YLy9MC1AVEq1hrTmC6Brt2jW1XQUCu53SyVYIRQZfNFwOcnVIbkZbGGHaddO7cUfg7afAmgI4Rx@wE2rU/X9Xxune8pRyArBP7LQlfO7dcain1uKt3EpmUsC7KBqNABKCEF5wFovkI@jrnueOj2BicyY@mJMGIzBItix@3Rmr4qPLmAZTn8jm6RbNina9/dnGyAs/vlBtlDADChBwH8zNcEIeI@TUaSQLdNbO5uZssj7qDHzvPAuVEGE8zXBaM0mAOd9s9htzXq@93BCbc1BFK/Abhzbic@uqmt21nFH/oZGclwpAJdY2O@2Xd3INJ1wsr9L6k7l6t5aUfNtwA4Ki@cB@35cDxdlQYc4dOPm28DEts082HlW@KG/FZ@/tv3w34HsOlwNtfjexE8CKZFDpDalLClnM1ROPSN3yW7OXUQiNZhQa2ca3qVWQpVF@vYxTxEBTm6VaDirICn9YdEBrBD0d22255yXc5SAZTt5ntYU8LO0wTITRVmsdlKkcjVplt14JMH/AoAzPeFbTMkagJ0uN04zScEAbNy3TyDREq71SGMmh9gwRggqgrRqX6uwznwERsdv1fNw1hVpxqVgOKFpTRUdmODvLr07CR@nMEjCHoa5rapYOaHpH1KSYdub4NfJbHAkij/yFK6OssB8yMAcqREph7dAv@EQedpzEHAmXrwoyLZIy/mEYoWwgNyoL3A39AwPBY6ixgbGvWddPwD82PxG@qpaIVi4q79ZRp4dcJ1v0S/QOOkoZtHxYHmlh4t18l9uIgpsROxY54P@bS@yF1Omp8A9nsEGhGT3TgP7ImxatEF36N4Z8mVHkRgfiqHZDXseMcppipRZL9VUz4u0TEIP0ey5mdYs0qjX4bhyC8VuRvSjJ7D4@jm6HLK/BxQ4@7GHH6EnRs/ugnT5GNuBpC9xjwmKcPNuceObqq0MYjXBczix5ULfMXP/IIGRw@UCiOwVH3Ronok@JBURrrmlwBbzJxezMyH@N25HLsbA9L6WII@R82vGKhg87R@Iq/t0CifgiyQ0b75tVjZS/lqNZYHJqUXjUWDE9iTSirvD5vfiB2EcdrtjYkCUPH7rwWgUeijYn6r2RFdW8v77hIlNf0T8cLT6JY1OIjecMz8DmsalNFUnlSHzE28uWdLXoy/a2TN7wEXZFsSSNSZBHCc4khUj6FQog6Y@QqsBgHuD1RmuMQCmgKZIQ3FVyAbtJkxfwSYOJCchjIxEPFU9BSBuikxp4b5mBm2nEefnvfnMTrIkcEKA6BrB8c0gmQEkLcl@kNWFVECdub1R5QG9CGWNmDcC@oEA3FlLXEDDKcbG6VJcq@4ojPUcpxGh9A8Ze6tPy@Zd2cczt11FjO9Hltma1vh@Hg4AzdtPmYV0gwLoWSy3QyAZqLo483Bini8uOK2mIIPYs@XJJPAAXQ1Ymve0L1Dx/nFmqQL6rRyQHQW617DuildtkLvki2pVz926oz68EhNshALrviD8rPemNUpC4WurW5ehO2DBcWEZVc1z1q/6ldBZlgD/9ecFX@IaCPefoTOwnxyUWJcJR0xgZJgGvPtLNPOLmIfMB7Cru/R2On62TCMnRsdVuiUH8jHaeTR6bw5lIpgN4b17mXOwmInBiYiDdozZ/m3EGJDlhjFsuQCwLJF7fDOG1wgOQ1ql9BcnjaHm5LYDaslDmhglahOU2Mz9M0hGrQY@665fVETwL3VHuzti792O@MEpr9CS7hYnzvmkIXVSt0neeRNZ7afjRxHBtduTfn4SRl9zNpxKs2R1kq2Jc65zgUfXxcBi3S/wHBOOs3tdVX5OJJGEMBzHmjfGGAzeg4POFewZ1ud67J3rstAc3l8Po4wA5j5aHUgWqXVAPQ5gBbgPpfBBf7gomN6aDTLq8s/xznLBLq3/iINVQ0F2NcZADQ3i060EBBEcTXs0Mgaok0s1cNTEjA4T4asX4aOwvQmJbcMatwHCyipEnwWFr3MEF6T0RrPwIjrPMDopWtEa3W@zvnCGSxiWer2V8S2hdXSgyDOMNedZFopE6WGLJGME8tYxWZpZkyQJBGq9QR3oVSays8GvVBY1kHzCfnQ7EsR5H7yYktY0bl/MJvzu0rGel5s8omX1Q@JIRFMUn9J/L3fK5ZgxtuwNknjzOFVrSQQHM5KidxtwsWkXYdCzbO3J2Y3nOEsyPkA8EOaQeJFpzFXga2GlXQIFYct0phgZ@TYoBjl4ZWhXtbJo9SUD9uptPaGze2nSHO1mkr7MKXhiVHteAhhjImOOfxIqx7Re18fSI7A@qVcBmvEA@V83BEHRrdiDg98JXWhIZ5uY8P7xBHNp/plwfZS8xSGWxqUbvMCINBNarfPB8JwwjUCCiU6QQfZdvvQ2Jo4@ZpJyFfNh@H7FcN@sQExFUseMX9cKGpQMsnLElt3fdWitZDUHvV@0GJVNd3KMcKZRG5A9pFwy8FU297i2V7llJOEtEw3lnS4Tc4kr9ACJMssKTyzaDLjDwh8iBglDRl@g@QVt/91k7wqmWlvzyB5tS4Z4awUoGXqVU6qPUnJwQNGFM1yPQremeY06giSyWuUl8QMkZdJXmfBKbFbyXXtFXVtJVnj3VtdCsQRQCdvYEErkMnkDSl7S6VpIWAp30ueg6JwY9okvCDKCYYQT42hsZc/kLVyVLLDOL0ktahJ3hQOq9mVNbopIrOeMM0hwNw3y@WsltsmeUtWNbxcSrpIKuZaVsuCA09h8pZUlshUEqYcs/1sJpe8XWzouSRnSuIsAnHZj5FC4z5Ui28c1@y6WPUk53Pvqab7cEkVCvlQ8o6vMRoU2fprPjMrrUyvQHpVidvJO0Uq@jR08l06cJUIXCy4lrzLPEBzhTLzsEBEtavCNgmDcQ5eJ3lPcrI6dmFK9l0WgXDH00geP7nItSbhlepKsaXRazvpauYRKEvEKrH1IyM@MTHJNTX95FpA1mQbI/28pthYmc4x8Wt6V1cvmmTXExpQeUhYQzOihup3KdmF3pYZTmX39/V@qBjUKNCSqrcXiIQXLWOS9zVDAn9MsifXNHRQ6Rkk4AW9i6x8trvcz9LTJmFUHmeh6fPzNF@S61y9zBIz/g2XhNWqPEzCy12BaXLDBXaq6h/TyT4rgVGBvHMZi0erJqGXqzIVSWu5KxMEu/89OeivgYs1CfMdcfrhQprlIj2@7@ZR3FTSeXmY5AOJGJgqELSQfJDOi78XIClDmXWZhIpZWTw7FueRnzYlUY7GYtc9q00qHEuZhBfIBa4kQYwxXSzhI7mpMSgaS/kQZBLmQDJZSW4NZ/xEZmw8jPAbGpV8ziQMDp49rvvbArIM@a0WVnWwgLRMfib5Hyl@5JQF2UpbHBB60YVN1HTGMjEqpOw6R/RqIRrzfa0GXVceVWMZK5BB2vNuK6Uxr18u/pJ3OIh2qghfNZZ3xnzLzzAFBGnyTD7SqIgc1O3ZjeFM/2bL8mJ5IBw/PT4f4o8F7ADa0zMRX@ZDY3ndPJ6W5UyUpQu2zlRDbJ0fshe@AcyNfVKtSNIOf0EIJ9W3aYljVG9Y1@HVhkJkjb0ovuaZfCEei0Rze718gXQW9GEsg3m@KiLXoL1IRf/cq69Kjb0kCjVx3yV1w98J/b7m/WTZ1xZsjX1aCtyFef31sujDWzNSQvfao5u8eLO859cqzT4T67jbWSCINv2kXfrG/gnwmLF/cjuLq/4niby2kCWXyWPI2D8DmlWhe4H14LxvFqQ@tH8WuP4BxvJDAyZ4JZCxz/pZPkCBfwyd006GuPyFhr@wBjulYa3ToVRSvtKLIdWJhTAeHx029r8JyMRqze2twbweTK89jsTkQf6L1qLBNUDYv0o4pvPcE8n2C@GiRrZtek@WcxIq7UUt/4z9m2weamWMiCHxa/u@wCmxe//7iKX2b72ko2gsS6I0Q/zLxZreuDYavQheC6R6x/7J1am8sZJcd8W/peVDWBgNNieoEBOL7hpzOoxl7NMNY@WzENk/12/BxF66yFewfqufmRj7dyywf1ckJUHZ5u2u3ZTYXB9BklDXfFmdu7H/wIK5Cot7@LU5KdhiPuZY8UvDS6GUsf/USxnX9a5lWV54H6Wd@ZA3P2F8OqZtsmQKv5MPZ9JNafopMV70fhdOzj4nPkmv7OBT@z25vbXP3b/I2OfFEgrqt@3z/pY4@ZDO@MfAQQxNL0AXYZcv@KITGM4BM/5IScxX/Fbn5FJtTnSPRUi4uDoQ/graSvtaFSuyf6GG2hd5k8ZtjL2sBjMQLpxemA8X5i0vTOw/eYWW@sXi6tziKuxEvqjdsE/Yl3gATYkb8Dln/6Hp3cjt9ayGe9G6f6mvGQgr86FcuKA9DesK@Ru3/xJBGstafuTe@hV/S3G4WWrxzrShqRITRZ8FsWz@qWRiF4y9qgm9TJSg@CiROnpP3WAdBneYs1eX0kwY6sYyJ1fXttj3dcfiKfBhXyCjoRId@ULTKcSMU66T73WGhu1TBdUS24E4qlT1GWNf8Zco@omCxuMvPsvlXnlAIqYKp4LjOWOZitsne98Y7CvcMbmR1grq8KN8tV8sWWbhqfRZ3irxsg5tQWOtfc1eala9G24iGNrXRUq8bPsjr95m5D61QJc5Km0Bci4sGPtGLyWua7EuHd4zbGyoBCfpGVhHB71yWT@2IDO2O/p5xrXr3tkcsra5wMJ6qiCCKxWDFS2Z1B7flC9i2d5dFK@IsNq@Kew6upXvf6bJ@gtoeIm3NC22L5ftW1IqXnq23ivD3PaUbQuuKNtYGLJqq9WgN8YyBa@crohHsVekcrBvP@DaJ8v6TQJJahAQ8TOo7u2/eRG9bLdh37CUzGlYPP4q1Fb779ZJvWAz9h31EzO9W1e6h5me0/Iv6jLsO3rGEiXHvNu@6zVDi4J2MQgUYgqu9ZTbbp10bdUU1wbZzLxT8wyIjCWjA3oJtRtrZ1mRWLbv0XSYeg@k9P5mICUWOWC7yJ@jEw3BfSVQORl7TRSjULFv@MtYhMp76y9GmXn8YQt7jSgT0XLLWCbd8m2p0mv2bj9FhXu9YndPAmfdt0Q2Hl0zlln3uSHkONGgfd9/QuaX1Fb/g8BkWUxCmMl8GyjWJ@0OZP@AV7h761t3NydXivfW25P9u91768/D4o1lwj3pFbLWu4ZV1SFr65MlTpXle054CvTuq/ZMlvRYlbyaYmmqeoaKte91XPxQSXTc2AO/7of5B@zB3U1@i7XX9Qa4Jh9DVaV1JzV7Y2@INdV7X4y4@ata06jCtQP5ctKJTtgb0QlUggVjmYSv2b@6raGJGbun8t9u6acm/4FnxH/h6X2MtkzI7YeTZdKKKuxrntE/E1AP1fIfXnCARW6@Fv2nf4/jx5m1WF4fPJ5ZezwK78s6Pr8w/k/7mTC@7@3TT/8P)

[Decompressor (small test case)](https://tio.run/##jVp7UxvX2f@/n0KLLS8CW0cSAglUCbBEMBch3PtleknbtPE27W6b3m@DCXGctO4F0VZJTGqbxAmJm1hgDPiSzmjteMaZOcP7FfRF8v5@z7MrcGY60xidPbv7POc898vZPP/c088/@8zzn3xiPmPwF94z4d2xvN21rbJtfSWwt@2Wbf7ENofstm@37Zrdqz9eHbOtx6vhHcLfNefCv9q1wdHJcMe2ussv2Fbdtg7u27bd6L58RRD7bbOHTZw7xu5WXBfA3YuX8Be@leJkeYWPbNPFzbjd8I@F@/6xnG1miLNv8HTs@@mT4d7j1XnHtsPboMJuZ8sVIAIvpWvhRjcn0p4g5R6v2t18tLyC5MZLT3Hj3THb5FvMbQtwACDerhnjU9tyy8KRbQLg4H66u7xsW5WxHF/ludq8d6JChNum5h@rjIWbADpJerBtd2kNkmpku0vNMdynsAteLL2GjYiyY84OjtodfyC85UVits3@ek9QY3kl@@IlQt8yiUfrtl2Mh50HLyXtRvh2Mdw@Domr4HLjtp0@2CL8trH7mWL4jt0f7C6/mJk9uNdduuwnZ/CXsPvhlm3NQz/Ly/k6obdMX0Ih@xIH907Ztb6wPe6ApWr9OAho6PLCadskZuzOYh9@g8MYkwf37Hagk4XuxTcm7f5CeNO2CHvThB/ILjSX7vJ528y6onbbGnfsxgkQftw282o2zSpRPjC6ht1IdC@@Igtig6M3vED77@s687ZNtPfN4kLYCma8xT4veTo54@GvaPf7vPDfwkEkxX@b4umirBdeAT1uNrxx0jaPx7YBfbsU4VO2SegbtJ7wWj58D7BZzCtiPCAV9IdN8KU8wRZoJuXywX2PeO@Zx6v9Q3aPfJ3PZWk@lfBd3KkNwSla3JFe0QKY8P2uURFz@ynbergHq36hQUfITFVlGbehu6ciXjaNGFRFjFYn405GiBLzU8MGS7hRGNg4iF4h8jswD9rFH3yYySSG4bO4HNwbljEzi6ezhHvbJJwzdqNAh/IwZiA62t318GKtZNuP1r3AqXX@Q9DrJnzRsWuebQ@Mhm9CSaXOvlMrlRKO8/DDtAAXHdXWWyaKD7QMobUltq6WoB5aGc@ccA/fEe1Ng60zgd0gbjqeDJ4KX8qohYQb3JY7TRJ@w6QzsMuRue7yhSMzz649Ws/wEr6OeydB2GsGBrCSwvY520oNwTmmRH3VrEtdTaTCq/NOCboTJ7hqhrpLVwQAulrN1aF5UZNtZUl7tBQ9@sdw9yiqXIE9vdLnFWe8hE/bTPinEz5vZrxC@C8JQQT7F3QTroRvQD/Tc0lxR7lOh//QRYceLPWrkoc0nr5hZrne7OnZGW92JlyH5Yf/hB6nEz@bW5yeWxwk0Lrx5uAdv5x5tL7Yh9/gKUrsz4Nn7WZ4mXtwCwJeNhAr3Xk6sPv8kZCAt/gtTi8yTBCYsK8biJIP0l74GtEGRpOdu5Bt@4dQxdwI5WvXZErw1wxlf6gFnSGe1dLhq4N2I8C@MLRJh8CvGu9bacxrMhx9qxvZNUK1jMSDxcMYYdvJOEogCgSUTHAaoYHQ/zTTEM4g2B2eLkrk4mWa@pCBrIk9/MOEf6cW7W5KFDNht@fD1TwVUBmaT09VxCdFz@qOf4fUEEOne2MctrgHbh@th2t2G2ltCphEWANCjbbq2FsI@Z4/UBulPY/O2a08Yj@eJcOXJTg0DaLlVOdatlwVD6lW6T8ZWGPZRaippGAHnavjacKuGsfx8AZkAbhfiIcd7jEcYGfl6buIPeHfxPcY2oj3N2P3MO/sSEzSFxgZ9vITcAnSLqGJMfHCoe39Ffshi52zO@cC2/6sc@4XyNyf5X/@OX/gXPgXAv3FOLPnoBForrv0RgYpLEH1@/4AnHhydNYLCsOnCPhnA9NMwkST4SW7qVLcpLoXowvNNTJPwl8ygC3a1x@tw4uigb4Aaf8pwj@lOiD0n@gn4R/t5txi9GP2ikZRXHQRh/mjERfpC18J7CbDot2cJYQOvYVlTvhX4AuzM/oTWkHFw/sMrkTX8eDeoN0m8MsGmvYHqPAA4FtV1c8LvytTWZB9PkvLKk/E9nXRpEtCjwZSca1P3UbxmNAvMdQgRI74eD44HM80Cmb0QrgLJlKzq1EXms4N0bhqkqbKkqZoEA@vVhWin2gvmoJjt@GB4D8tUzjmZMmbhIkMhi98LfBl9RXT5xVOFxDeZrxJCXmT/ulJnzfqji8YspCepLiQZuTa@dCXpbtL@3YnXD6VHHFQJoF4IiybkVkvPG/XEhoORqAuj5z9XCNCpJMvE/a8ySTCJdiaR9lsg6Zo7guWbculRNAlxCW4vj8yS1aikdAUKa@1hMgLma4UeXX7NxnEQ/ktZqLok4EhyY@gH5ozTFDFzn2wkLA7smbB8/EbHAYJO0lC3TcZbFIsaV7FbE6wOggeg0KRYkqs69wzeD0SpB@tBzWxBX8EPndGh4Q3wsjVuQvL8mYdJDgMnTtOmsGOEZnZl9agztC5YzRuzzqMwqeSghWFZsCm5ULAfVPiXk5CQuqjdUJjyaP3nb0ibmSKfE@kPeMU8EgC3Cwnkdyczm6J2KUewjA10Nk1BLc7I2Kvgtu5PYlxgWsGvya4VxIsWk7ntlFYhzCZSE1PThf8gVE1B6FoB6a@knXLE7DjnEbiw5gYR/LOLda6tHmXOLcMA76bSx3cZ@6vSjTtr7KdsXu5znY@P5EfGpdGh@Db9KbOllvlElV4TSoKsNXGBAOoU5vSBxWG3M6WaWTrruT0Vqct@@bcIfH@rKsJ/lmsLr5I@LZJodztoLhGTVlxJ3Jorca/XclKqzYBqj6@AMg8QW@azFQuYg2vOx@kel6dbyBluNKQkAnNRp0PhFNkjFR36TpLY2SJXGOigR1KEgo672ddSGWCvUvnfVbG1X5mliGuIpUPMOLCh5fxmr07L6LJf7QDJHvXxAIHbOdGtqosTqDDG09PafGUj55RwtzoBorcal5FlOOqKLSY9sqS2DRSkpXOeyo3psvOe1oZa@ZqKhbSJbfQJsxt0Ag67@bz/RrUiPWuSY2zOAeX5f4jGZNsNUhBZ5P8zjuxOjYNlMeVO@9IL5HLkRXUCemYTzcr6XKC0O@YtGpEOkHbbGgtl0vFqZx1o9vvQqKdt4nwtlHtpKQ7lSKUuPxp9TzVuY4yoV85pBaIdd1ENgc0t/NWpVdylLN5yeOU27YwWib8W6YiRS88gqvyOUF@312@AUvPqaVHK3betLtfJdKbEHA50gqTlOJqyRxvLtKnlDdYKqWItmGqMSStgvaeh9oqPanQfCbqqXHHmyI8anIpsbMNN268pIVCGFu5ls2JM0Z9TWvem3JZkhHvKmv587T7B@dpswpTdYG54R@Tng17SXYDAxTDg/NGCyvxtuXlSIZD4obukV1qJ/C4LkYEtId7RjpDhRESMc7TYVjBsUi3zVQkQWUFrR8RPzTaGWkQ6xWKRx4dtksPXjIDBQa1h1d6RXDAmkvywsNmwtEZC6iHTRPBdJfuOJp07EYRFuYVHe8Us@pNyQeABYTRlZhy1sA5anJH806aM008zAySfh5eNSqWHItCSmYCfRLVHkW5HA1saF7rT26wcs3U1LKJ8Hj148v1x6vUwtGH/WLS0i67aglA/fiy6Y8euxIvywovpopo4cZlS14fCjuoqHcbcbcrtoKW2G48Rc8aQ3tZlRe5KmlgoyxdfnepaSpleVPmi@7SNbtxkq35mIQ0tXB5XxHEpwTpmvFO0MvHJHmAhqX1g/s0HcVyy3rkId16DmQI0rpx3bgVrxBAncE/Vo8WIpcKUQeVgnPZ8PBmAW0Mf8NnF1BxDHNYWFz4qc9GZ@lVAXzVFABT0GOchQLeFGYCv7vU6rNrM/5in7/I4x0BbaHD7At8GfT4JvBnYAH7fRyGz@KCTWh6S4ZnCi9fqTf661IH0lmzH92WXCU6@xyN3VV/@Oi2aVTixndIA89KZBzkTHNdsz6e6RkA7eq@ictlqewfXPiV3SywXiYzGIVEvW6SqAumV3zHOHwVEAXD4NfZ39lN6e@4/qrJCoUMR3VGIOmcGv2Rb1alzU9JwBLx7ButFneSZ1AEjvaN@nQZf2TyDP9mWX88vGLEJTmwNj07DBBWVonoQTpwPNTi6mc3zXC66PjqpoTiHZwugYDrYaix3/j4ArbtLl2NLJu5FkKcZ82gp0h5dqEUazsjq16VUxTJnETQdkGygW0qj2K7@X7hksYqaFdMVFJopZPTVi46y8iWmTJZLEipIgjXTVw6lLX@0aQQxUgx23Kqd5bLUmlK8N4wNQ/F7Rrr2eQAqnvf/2h1AM3@JOrXYtT/0WpWzQCPmHYwziXjGUd2RmteoeBNQqyy5mtGgwY9RPybhdnyck6Pghv6Rs5r9Ri4doKVx@tGWsKi9PeczOhPjmH0oq0e91i@YdROt@ed9FSvET6sHChfVxLZhvbZjOgocRrSiseyVnFCi9Cay0INSS0XVSh/MLDNsxkMGe4tgxzTJnx5hIEHWL83bn996DABu3E4EvqY2jMRfV@KM9LvjDSS42k5sPPtbY9N5poXaCqHBf62yg7ut4ZHzMDB@jt2C7Ue1TnxIzkJpZ/kKdDDUM1q@DdG2su4Ro@6Tb3NwO/400wG4F/zWCZdKgVygXPIzB/p1eR6/wxAf2UCddbNhHTJIo1hXuXsS3yfc4D@0swlT88lZ7w5nhEEor3erpzzKeB@bob9XmvIWcGbk5FiSSRlCrCfGR6SPX9wD7LnMQ3782m09/zxJGiWt3oq9jyj63QUXacLeiqHyzT72ngA3E@NnI8t8AiKPzIjAyI3mRheYJP2E2ObUj33Tvsll@hRZ70c1RE1NS/4PFX2Y/Od6MBYfFXOZrRpiQpu@WrSFpPoQVBvP8Jmqfnn8hVW1S0pCA@29JODppv@@udJyXHAPmeirzbRRxu7l7fNL6ZhRKVR2/4C6WTJD5NhB/NDE/WU8OgMf@JFk3quNzgcTZzge4B9VhoMiTY8LI1c5DAtVNwfaLWV0nT@AzM0HsVpV7jOSRjMVfkeYbE0FbUu3zcVSi0nn2MchzlYI9GYBAipRONvTRQAwwLQnjG025IcTtqN0qcmfKdGcXjPPvV7RsIXsoKeKTijvRNOhGK6hHbF6dKgI0XTd03OlbgNHYxLC9KIInW9EtXhDVfOfb9jhuLMxEDytJAblTLyxaHXJlBMAAHO00ajt3sYvlO1yONREctT9ocA/bZBAIpitgSmPPJLS9AZm5jFNVGoVL9l5FTWK36jd@6a0FwLhr@Z9gpONAfsN5Hejrzly5IMcr5wFPIbRqEGWJV6xaM3wC/JKiUWHl83Z5HLESRltJuL@MM8KU8k2xcZKjAA@GvGH5EvDxvxVfN1/DVCci7gvmqkxFzhWa5wrN9hIMq8dI8rvealyiwIjK8YtZtU1HfoJwu6alU@WFR7rUGzBwHfAuaXjYYdYW/EGfV8Dnqkc3ie9SUj1WK5qoUROp9a1BlJJyi5pBXrjD3UF00Ur8lHZaKiRDNSp2OfdnPiu0PC8hdMOjIH8dmy9tapeWmiBbAVg37eaOoSNytXmedymgRKnwJGUAD854x0leWo3tvmN9mampybjYWJFgFvos@xZ9luFDBZNElRXEO6LuatBWN3JMXXDQRL0c@j6oArYTaH8pChdZZlIn1qBvUfU/UZw4qKx2jTxm7ykOcpo8GrSQEcfnCeMgdb/7eMSQ3bCClV7Cxucdr00gfVNok9mEAmWItJHBoHHVy6AsK0IirzIEmQS4Am1hgiLOWL6agJ@KQI0khqgRtyMmJ84W/YsJtiDsgb@W5N7ocoeuogx21lkywf8atXBitwxTRWJOWnsIBPnk@aWOOSNmgsSCYbgaf6PuR@0LDSJBEpCpf79BsUoyTX5ROycuLIatFa/uH86Nf7JEoHquM4Kdzxntwvuo9PtQF2zBzseXx9@xDUf5LmeOU@MQKJzg51zUkCzwIpyy4YfyDwhA94EaUAOlhdBpGIKcvHq1rlQnVskLdkvhzx9iQBT/wvCQx6Qo5qkYZHAvSfPLhEdlsyfcVIUQtugyO7o@X1Y1ZlETQryo@EOa4CBfrUJYxfQ5/vqQFhYbstlGMtn/zCB1Twoi8YryqH/BFS3/AqvPSe9P6RqYP7FIIXsND2zvHBvXhfPIIwZaeDPZTfbdLt@aTHP5zabd5T2QdbxleoQ6AnYISLPZhVZAC48LEKYtccUgaZ@0HPToQ6BbptsCBu@DEM5MkXMSHfU/e3O1hdJrdMBPE/DcTYNh47DWwk@/qBF6i021xTVsW97w0EgQACy/Oj/8xnzjmO/wu7898@cTmz5yTF@Z988v8)

Explanation: simple dictionary-based approach. The decompressor performs the same substitions as the compressor, but in reverse order. Note that both these programs take input by concatenating it into the source, as is usual for ///.